# Efficient creation of lists from other lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following lists:

```
v1 = {a, c, e};

v2 = {b, d, f};
```

how does one efficiently create the following "combination lists"?

```
{a, c, e};
{a, c, f};
{a, d, e};
{a, d, f};
{b, c, e};
{b, c, f};
{b, d, e};
{b, d, f};
```

How can one generalize the algorithm to lists `v1` and `v2` of arbitrary but equal length $n$?

Comment: `Tuples[Transpose@{v1,v2}]` should do it. That will also generalize to any length for v1,v2. Assuming the lengths of v1 v2 are the same.

Comment: Congratulations on your first Statue Badge, @N.J.Evans!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured I should make this an answer so it can be closed.

What you're looking for is all combinations of three elements such that the first element is either `{a,b}`, the second element is either `{c,d}`, and the last element is either `{e,f}`. Where the choices for each element come from two given vectors `v1={a,c,e}`, and `v2={b,d,f}`. This is what `Tuples` is meant to do.

In order to get the answer you're after you need to manipulate the vectors a bit.

Using `Transpose@{v1,v2}` gives a list `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}`. Passed to `Tuples` in this form, the function will create all possible combinations of the three sublists. This is the second form given in the documentation.

So the answer is simply,

`Tuples[Transpose@{v1,v2}]`

This can also be generalized to any number of vectors of any length, as long as the vectors have the same length. `Tuples[Transpose@{v1,v2,v3}]`.

---

The only problem with vectors of different lengths is the `Transpose` operation. So with some assumptions about the vectors, vectors with different lengths can be handled using a trick from @The Toad for transposing uneven lists, [Transpose uneven lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/transpose-uneven-lists).

`Tuples[{v1,v2,vSmaller}~Flatten~{2}]`

For instance:

```
v1 = {1,2,3};
v2 = {6,7};
Tuples[{v1,v2}~Flatten~{2}]
```

Gives:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 7, 3}, {6, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 3}}
```