# Manipulating list with sub-lists of different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list, which is composed of sublists with different lengths

```
{{}, {{2, 2}, {7, 2}}, {{6, 3}}, {{5, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}}, {}, {{6, 3}}}
```

How can this list be transformed into a list of the first elements, second elements, etc...i.e, the out come I would like to produce

```
{{{2, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}}, {{7, 2}, {5, 5}, {4, 7}}, {{4, 8}}}
```

Comment: related: [Transpose uneven lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3643/106)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
data = {{}, {{2, 2}, {7, 2}}, {{6, 3}}, {{5, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}}, {}, {{6, 3}}};
get[a_, k_] := Map[If[Length[#] >= k, #[[k]], Nothing] &, a];
get[data, 1]
get[data, 2]
get[data, 3]
get[data, 4]
```

> {{2, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}}
>
> {{7, 2}, {5, 5}, {4, 7}}
>
> {{4, 8}}
>
> {}

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten):

```
list = {
    {},
    {{2,2},{7,2}},
    {{6,3}},
    {{5,4},{5,5}},
    {{4,6},{4,7},{4,8}},
    {},
    {{6,3}}
};

Flatten[list, {2}]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}}, {{7, 2}, {5, 5}, {4, 7}}, {{4, 8}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{}, {{2, 2}, {7, 2}}, {{6, 3}}, {{5, 4}, {5, 5}},
   {{4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}}, {}, {{6, 3}}};

Extract[lst, #] & /@ GatherBy[Position[lst, _, {2}, Heads -> False], Last]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}},
>     {{7, 2}, {5, 5}, {4, 7}},
>   {{4, 8}}}

or

```
parts[l_][k_] := Join @@ MapIndexed[If[Last[#2] == k, #, ## &[]] &, l, {2}]
parts[lst] /@ Range[4]]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}},
>    {{7, 2}, {5, 5}, {4,  7}},
>    {{4, 8}},
>   {}}