# Best way to create symmetric matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, matrix

From time to time I need to generate symmetric matrices with relatively expensive cost of element evaluation. Most frequently these are [Gram matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) where elements are $L_2$ dot products. Here are two ways of efficient implementation which come to mind: memoization and direct procedural generation.

```
ClearAll[el, elmem];
el[i_, j_] := Integrate[ChebyshevT[i, x] ChebyshevT[j, x], {x, -1, 1}];
elmem[i_, j_] := elmem[j, i] = el[i, j];

n = 30;
ClearSystemCache[];
a1 = Table[el[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]; // Timing
ClearSystemCache[];
a2 = Table[elmem[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]; // Timing
ClearSystemCache[];
(a3 = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
  Do[a3[[i, j]] = a3[[j, i]] = el[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i}];) // Timing
a1 == a2 == a3
```

---

```
{34.75, Null}

{18.235, Null}

{18.172, Null}

True
```

Here `a1` is a redundant version for comparison, `a2` is using memoization, `a3` is a procedural-style one which I don't really like but it beats the built-in function here. The results are quite good but I wonder **if there are more elegant ways of generating symmetric matrices?**

---

**SUMMARY (UPDATED)**

Thanks to all participants for their contributions. Now it's time to benchmark. Here is the compilation of all proposed methods with minor modifications.

```
array[n_, f_] := Array[f, {n, n}];
arraymem[n_, f_] := 
  Block[{mem}, mem[i_, j_] := mem[j, j] = f[i, j]; Array[mem, {n, n}]];
proc[n_, f_] := Block[{res},
  res = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]; 
  Do[res[[i, j]] = res[[j, i]] = f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i}];
  res
  ]

acl[size_, fn_] := 
  Module[{rtmp}, rtmp = Table[fn[i, j], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, i}];
   MapThread[Join, {rtmp, Rest /@ Flatten[rtmp, {{2}, {1}}]}]];

RM1[n_, f_] := 
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} :> f[i, j] /; i >= j, {i_, j_} :> f[j, i]}, n];
RM2[n_, f_] := 
  Table[{{i, j} -> #, {j, i} -> #} &@f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i}] // 
    Flatten // SparseArray;

MrWizard1[n_, f_] := 
  Join[#, Rest /@ #~Flatten~{2}, 2] &@Table[i~f~j, {i, n}, {j, i}];
MrWizard2[n_, f_] := Max@##~f~Min@## &~Array~{n, n};

MrWizard3[n_, f_] := Block[{f1, f2},
  f1 = LowerTriangularize[#, -1] + Transpose@LowerTriangularize[#] &@
     ConstantArray[Range@#, #] &;
  f2 = {#, Reverse[(Length@# + 1) - #, {1, 2}]} &;
  f @@ f2@f1@n
  ]


whuber[n_Integer, f_] /; n >= 1 := 
  Module[{data, m, indexes}, 
   data = Flatten[Table[f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i, n}], 1];
   m = Binomial[n + 1, 2] + 1;
   indexes = 
    Table[m + Abs[j - i] - Binomial[n + 2 - Min[i, j], 2], {i, n}, {j,
       n}];
   Part[data, #] & /@ indexes];

JM[n_Integer, f_, ori_Integer: 1] := 
  Module[{tri = Table[f[i, j], {i, ori, n + ori - 1}, {j, ori, i}]}, 
   Fold[ArrayFlatten[{{#1, Transpose[{Most[#2]}]}, {{Most[#2]}, 
        Last[#2]}}] &, {First[tri]}, Rest[tri]]];

generators = {array, arraymem, proc, acl, RM1, RM2, MrWizard1, 
   MrWizard2, MrWizard3, whuber, JM};
```

The first three procedures are mine, all other are named after their authors.
Let's start from cheap `f` and (relatively) large dimensions.

```
fun = Cos[#1 #2] &;
ns = Range[100, 500, 50]
data = Table[ClearSystemCache[]; Timing[gen[n, fun]] // First,
   {n, ns}, {gen, generators}];
```

Here is a logarithmic diagram for this test:

```
<< PlotLegends`

ListLogPlot[data // Transpose, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, DataRange -> {Min@ns, Max@ns}, 
 PlotLegend -> generators, LegendPosition -> {1, -0.5}, 
 LegendSize -> {.5, 1}, ImageSize -> 600, Ticks -> {ns, Automatic}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"n", "time"}]
```

[image]

Now let's make `f` numeric:

```
fun = Cos[N@#1 #2] &;
```

The result is quite surprising:

[image]

As you may guess, the missed quantities are machine zeroes.

The last experiment is old: it doesn't include fresh `MrWizard3` and RM's codes are with `//Normal`. It takes "expensive" `f` from above and tolerant `n`:

```
fun = Integrate[ChebyshevT[#1 , x] ChebyshevT[#2, x], {x, -1, 1}] &;
ns = Range[10, 30, 5]
```

The result is

[image]

As we see, all methods which do not recompute the elements twice behave identically.

Comment: The timing bottleneck is not the list construction but the integration. So as long as you perform the same number of integrals, I wouldn't expect any significant difference in the `Timing` results, no matter how you loop over the elements. The first example just calculates some integrals twice, but as long as you avoid that I don't see much room for improvement. However in your specific example the integrals can be done analytically, so that would of course speed things up.

Comment: It looks like I didn't manage to express my motivation. The question is about the best way to create symmetric matrices, not just in this particular case. You know, the ideal would be an option for `Table`, something like `Symmetric->True`. I don't like preliminary allocating and implicit indexing, since I always try to avoid procedural things when using Mathematica, just for self-education. Memoization is quite nice but it will fail for large dimensions.

Comment: One possibility is to just generate an upper or lower triangle, and then make use of `Transpose[]` and `UpperTriangularize[]`/`LowerTriangularize[]` to generate the other half.

Comment: @J.M. you can do this as in my answer; what do you think?

Comment: Yep, quite better than my suggestion, @acl. :)

Comment: @faleichik Could you also check to see if mine has similar performance without the `Normal`? Because that's almost never needed and I added it only to get the display

Comment: faleichik, thanks for the accept; I added another method to my answer for your interest and amusement.

Comment: RM, done, but there's no changes I'm afraid... Mr.Wizard: clear victory :-)

Comment: @faleichik Prestidigitonium! :-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Borrowing liberally from acl's answer:

```
sim = Join[#, Rest /@ # ~Flatten~ {2}, 2] & @ Table[i ~#~ j, {i, #2}, {j, i}] &;

sim[Subscript[x, ##] &, 5] // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & x_{3,1} & x_{4,1} & x_{5,1} \\
 x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{3,2} & x_{4,2} & x_{5,2} \\
 x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} & x_{4,3} & x_{5,3} \\
 x_{4,1} & x_{4,2} & x_{4,3} & x_{4,4} & x_{5,4} \\
 x_{5,1} & x_{5,2} & x_{5,3} & x_{5,4} & x_{5,5}
\end{array}$

Trading efficiency for brevity:

```
sim2[f_, n_] := Max@## ~f~ Min@## & ~Array~ {n, n}

sim2[Subscript[f, ##] &, 5] // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & x_{3,1} & x_{4,1} & x_{5,1} \\
 x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{3,2} & x_{4,2} & x_{5,2} \\
 x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} & x_{4,3} & x_{5,3} \\
 x_{4,1} & x_{4,2} & x_{4,3} & x_{4,4} & x_{5,4} \\
 x_{5,1} & x_{5,2} & x_{5,3} & x_{5,4} & x_{5,5}
\end{array}$

---

Just for fun, here's a method for fast vectorized (`Listable`) functions such as your "cheap `f`" test, showing what's possible if you keep everything packed. (`Cos` function given a numeric argument so that it evaluates.)

```
f1 = LowerTriangularize[#, -1] + Transpose@LowerTriangularize[#] & @
       ConstantArray[Range@#, #] &;

f2 = {#, Reverse[(Length@# + 1) - #, {1, 2}]} &;

f3 = # @@ f2@f1 @ #2 &;

f3[Cos[N@# * #2] &, 500]  // timeAvg

sim[Cos[N@# * #2] &, 500] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00712
>
> 0.1436

Comment: The amazing, shrinking code

Comment: @acl I try. :-)

Comment: please link to `timeAvg` for future users

Comment: @R.M I linked to it in several of my other posts.  Here's the full code again for reference: `timeAvg = 
  Function[func, 
   Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
     15}], HoldFirst];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know where to find it... others might not know what it means or where to look for it.

Comment: @R.M I know you know I know you know ;-) where to find it; yes, I got lazy this time and didn't link it but it wouldn't be hard to search the site for `timeAvg` and find it.  I'll try to remember to include it in the future.

Comment: <must.resist.urge.to.continue.the.train>!

Comment: @all great Q&A! Helped me to optimize some of my costly integral table calculations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, how can I extend this to a NxNxN (rank 3) tensor or even a rank 4 tensor? I have tried some options, but cannot get through the used syntax here.

Answer (score 12):

## Proposed solution

If `fn[i,j]` produces the $(i,j)^{th}$ element, then

```
makeSym[size_, fn_] := Module[
  {rtmp},
  rtmp = Table[
    fn[i, j],
    {i, 1, size},
    {j, 1, i}];
  MapThread[
   Join,
   {rtmp, Rest /@ Flatten[rtmp, {{2}, {1}}]}
   ]
  ]
```

does what you want.

## Example

```
makeSym[5, Subscript[f, #1, #2] &] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## How does it work?

### Idea

Produce half the matrix, then do a "ragged transpose" and finally zip the results together.

### Step by step

First, we construct half the matrix with a `Table`: For an example `size` of 5, we have

```
With[{size = 5},rtmp=Table[fn[i, j], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, i}]]

(*
{ {fn[1, 1]}, 
  {fn[2, 1], fn[2, 2]}, 
  {fn[3, 1], fn[3, 2], fn[3, 3]}, 
  {fn[4, 1], fn[4, 2], fn[4, 3], fn[4, 4]}, 
  {fn[5, 1], fn[5, 2], fn[5, 3], fn[5, 4], fn[5, 5]}}
*)
```

Next, use the form of `Flatten` described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/16) and in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) to do a "ragged transpose":

```
Flatten[rtmp, {{2}, {1}}]
(*
{ {fn[1, 1], fn[2, 1], fn[3, 1], fn[4, 1], fn[5, 1]}, 
  {fn[2, 2], fn[3, 2], fn[4, 2], fn[5, 2]}, 
  {fn[3, 3], fn[4, 3], fn[5, 3]}, 
  {fn[4, 4], fn[5, 4]}, 
  {fn[5, 5]}}
*)
```

then drop the first element of each (to avoid duplicating it), by mapping `Rest`:

```
Rest /@ Flatten[rtmp, {{2}, {1}}]

(*
{ {fn[2, 1], fn[3, 1], fn[4, 1], fn[5, 1]}, 
  {fn[3, 2], fn[4, 2], fn[5, 2]}, 
  {fn[4, 3], fn[5, 3]}, 
  {fn[5, 4]}, 
  {}}
*)
```

And finally, zip together the corresponding pieces (ie, the $i^{th}$ line of the last result with the $i^{th}$ of `rtmp`), using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[
 Join,
 {rtmp, Rest /@ Flatten[rtmp, {{2}, {1}}]}
 ]

(*
{ {fn[1, 1], fn[2, 1], fn[3, 1], fn[4, 1], fn[5, 1]}, 
  {fn[2, 1], fn[2, 2], fn[3, 2], fn[4, 2], fn[5, 2]}, 
  {fn[3, 1], fn[3, 2], fn[3, 3], fn[4, 3], fn[5, 3]}, 
  {fn[4, 1], fn[4, 2], fn[4, 3], fn[4, 4], fn[5, 4]}, 
  {fn[5, 1], fn[5, 2], fn[5, 3], fn[5, 4], fn[5, 5]}}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple and clean way to generate symmetric matrices (in general) would be the following:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} :> f[i, j] /; i >= j, {i_, j_} :> f[j, i]}, 5] // Normal

(* {{f[1, 1], f[2, 1], f[3, 1], f[4, 1], f[5, 1]}, 
    {f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[3, 2], f[4, 2], f[5, 2]}, 
    {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3], f[4, 3], f[5, 3]}, 
    {f[4, 1], f[4, 2], f[4, 3], f[4, 4], f[5, 4]}, 
    {f[5, 1], f[5, 2], f[5, 3], f[5, 4], f[5, 5]}} *)
```

The `Normal` is necessary only if you don't want a `SparseArray` object (generally, it doesn't matter). If your function `f` is expensive, you can do something like

```
Table[{{i, j} -> #, {j, i} -> #} &@f[i, j], {i, 5}, {j, i}] // Flatten // SparseArray
```

which evaluates `f` only $N(N+1)/2$ times instead of $N^2$.

Comment: +1 for the idea I didn't write up myself despite plenty of time to do so. :)

Answer (score 3):

I might as well. Here's my variation, which uses a "bordering" method to build up a symmetric matrix from a triangular array:

```
tri = Table[C[i, j], {i, 5}, {j, i}];

Fold[ArrayFlatten[{{#1, Transpose[{Most[#2]}]}, {{Most[#2]}, Last[#2]}}] &,
     {First[tri]}, Rest[tri]]

{{C[1, 1], C[2, 1], C[3, 1], C[4, 1], C[5, 1]},
 {C[2, 1], C[2, 2], C[3, 2], C[4, 2], C[5, 2]},
 {C[3, 1], C[3, 2], C[3, 3], C[4, 3], C[5, 3]},
 {C[4, 1], C[4, 2], C[4, 3], C[4, 4], C[5, 4]},
 {C[5, 1], C[5, 2], C[5, 3], C[5, 4], C[5, 5]}}
```

Here's a demonstration of why the method is called "bordering":

[image: matrix bordering]

Here's a function that acts like `Array[]`:

```
SymmetricArray[f_, n_Integer, ori_Integer: 1] := 
 Module[{tri = Table[f[i, j], {i, ori, n + ori - 1}, {j, ori, i}]}, 
        Fold[ArrayFlatten[{{#1, Transpose[{Most[#2]}]}, {{Most[#2]}, Last[#2]}}] &,
             {First[tri]}, Rest[tri]]]
```

Try it out:

```
SymmetricArray[Min, 5]
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Commenters have pointed out there is no timing gain.  But, in the hopes of stimulating better answers from others, here's a start.

```
SymmetricTable[f_, n_Integer] /; n >= 1 := Module[{data, m, indexes},
   data = Flatten[Table[f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i, n}], 1];
   m = Binomial[n + 1, 2] + 1;
   indexes = Table[m + Abs[j - i] - Binomial[n + 2 - Min[i, j], 2], {i, n}, {j, n}];
   Part[data, #] & /@ indexes
   ];
```

It tabulates the upper triangle of `f`, flattens it into a vector (`data`), computes a symmetric array of subscripts into that vector (`indexes`), and applies those subscripts to the vector to obtain the symmetrized square table.  Whether that is "elegant" or not will be somewhat subjective.

As an example of usage:

```
f = Function[{i, j}, Sow[{i, j}];  10 i + j];
Reap[SymmetricTable[f, 5] // MatrixForm]
```

This returns a symmetric table of values of `f` along with a list of the arguments that were passed to `f` when constructing this table, verifying that the minimum number of calls to `f` were actually made.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

**What about**

```
Table[x[Max[i, j], Min[i, j]], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Out]

Comment: This is basically a conversion of `sim2` in the [answer by Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7968/18476) into an easier to read `Table` version.