# Interpolating and plotting a surface for a sparse set of 3d data points

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, interpolation

I have a set of $(x,y,z)$ coordinates which sparsely cover a surface, e.g.:

```
data = {{51, 15, 0.1}, {300, 11, 0.99}, {140, 22, 0.123}, {54, 12, 0.66}, ...};
```

What is a good general method, in *Mathematica* 9, of interpolating and plotting a surface for this sparse data set? `Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[data]]` doesn't seem to get the job done; the output is a planar rectangle.

Comment: Have you tried `ListPlot3D`?

Comment: `Interpolation` works for multidimensional functions but You have to be sure that there are no duplicates in {x,y} with different z. `Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data]`

Comment: You might want to look into [thin plate splines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11817)...

Comment: @m_goldberg ListPlot3D seems to do what I'd like, so thanks!  But do you know what interpolation method is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `InterpolationOrder` to control the degree of smoothing.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[10, {20, 3}];
Column[
 ListPlot3D[data,
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    Mesh -> None,
    InterpolationOrder -> #] & /@ Range[0, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Setting `InterpolationOrder` greater than 1 doesn't seem to make a difference unless you have regular data (sampled on a grid)...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with *ListPointPlot3D*.

ListPoint3D generates a 3D scattered plot of points with coordinates {xi,yi,zi}.

Since you're a bit avaricious with your data, here the plot with your data:

```
data = {{51, 15, 0.1}, {300, 11, 0.99}, {140, 22, 0.123}, {54, 12, 0.66}};
ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], Filling -> Bottom,
   ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to use BSpline, just take a BSplineCurve, if your data does not produce a decent surface:

```
Graphics3D[{BSplineCurve[data], PointSize[Medium], Green, Line[data], 
    Red, Point[data]}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2}]
```

[image]

**Edit2:**

For a BSplineSurface (with qualified data) you can do something like:

```
data=Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Map[Point, data], Gray, 
    Line[data], Line[Transpose[data]]}], Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[data]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically looking for a surface!

Comment: so why not pasting your data completely?