# How can I speed up my compiled RBF interpolating function?

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation, compile

**Overview**

I have a function that acts like the `Interpolation` on sparse $n$-dimensional data using a simple  implementation of [RBF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) interpolation method. I want my function to return a compiled function that will run fast. What I get works but it is much slower that I think it should be.

**My code**

```
Clear[RBFInterpolation]

Options[RBFInterpolation] = {
    "DistanceFunction" -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &), 
    "RadialBasisFunction" -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2/4] &), 
    "RadialScale" -> Automatic, "Debug" -> False, "Compile" -> False};

RBFInterpolation[cptab_, opts : OptionsPattern[RBFInterpolation]] := 
Module[
{ro, xpts, fundata, Φ, disfun, λ, RBF, x}, 

xpts = #[[1]] & /@ cptab;
fundata = #[[2]] & /@ cptab;
disfun = OptionValue["DistanceFunction"];
RBF = OptionValue["RadialBasisFunction"];

Φ = 
 Table[disfun[xpts[[i]], xpts[[j]]], {i, 1, Length[xpts]},{j,1,Length[xpts]}];

Which[
 OptionValue["RadialScale"] == Automatic,
 ro = Median[
  Flatten[Table[
    Drop[Φ[[i]], {i}], {i, 1, 
     Length[Φ]}]]],

NumberQ[OptionValue["RadialScale"]],
ro = OptionValue["RadialScale"],

True,
Print["I cannot understand \"RadialScale\"->", 
 OptionValue["RadialScale"], " So I'm going to make it up"];
ro = Median[
  Flatten[Table[
    Drop[Φ[[i]], {i}], {i, 1, Length[Φ]}]]]
]; 

If[OptionValue["Debug"], Print["ro=", ro]];
If[OptionValue["Debug"],
  Print["Distance function on first two points"];
  Print["point 1 ->", xpts[[1]]];
  Print["point 2 ->", xpts[[2]]];
  Print["Distance ->", disfun[xpts[[1]], xpts[[2]]]];
  Print["Radial Basis Function on Distance ->", 
  RBF[disfun[xpts[[1]], xpts[[2]]], ro]]
];

Φ = Map[RBF[#, ro] &, Φ, {2}];

If[OptionValue["Debug"], 
    Print["Element of Φ[[1,1]]=", Φ[[1,1]]]];

λ = Inverse[Φ].fundata;

If[OptionValue["Debug"], 
 Print["First element of λ[[1]]=", λ[[i]]]];

If[OptionValue["Compile"],
 Return[
  With[{xi = x, λi = λ, xptsi = xpts, roi = ro}, 
  Compile[{{xi, _Real, 1}}, 
   Sum[λi[[i]] RBF[disfun[xi, xptsi[[i]]], roi], {i, 1, 
     Length[λ]}]]]],

 Return[
  Function[x, 
   Sum[λ[[i]] RBF[disfun[x, xpts[[i]]], ro], {i, 1, 
    Length[λ]}]]]
  ]
 ];
```

Most of this function is not of interest to my question. I think the key is where I `Return[]` the compiled function.

```
Return[
  With[{xi = x, λi = λ, xptsi = xpts, roi = ro}, 
  Compile[{{xi, _Real, 1}}, 
   Sum[λi[[i]] RBF[disfun[xi, xptsi[[i]]], roi], {i, 1, 
     Length[λ]}]]]]
```

**Testing the Function**

The following code can be used to run and test the timing of the returned function.

First make a "Truth" function to sample then interpolate

```
Clear[truth]
truth[x_] := Product[Sin[x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}];
```

Make up some data

```
n = 100;
d = 5;
cpts = RandomReal[{-π/2, π/2}, {n, d}];
cptab = {#, truth[#]} & /@ cpts;
xpts = #[[1]] & /@ cptab;
fundata = #[[2]] & /@ cptab;
```

Test the speed of the returned functions

```
Print["Normal Function:"];
Timing[funFun = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> False];]
Timing[funFun[#] & /@ xpts;]

Print["Compile Function:"];
Timing[funFunc = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> True];]
Timing[funFunc[#] & /@ xpts;]
i = 1;
Print["Normal function: ", funFun[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["Complie function: ", funFunc[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["The real right answer: ", fundata[[i]]];
```

I get results like this:

```
Normal Function:
{0.080987,Null}
{0.123981,Null}

Compile Function:
{0.092986,Null}
{0.156977,Null}

Normal function: -0.0182901
Complie function: -0.0182901
The real right answer: -0.0182901
```

So as you can see it works but it is not faster. How do I make this faster?

**Simpler test that is faster!?**

The code:

```
n = 10;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
f = Table[2 π i, {i, 1, n}];
ϕ = RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, n];
Clear[Nfun]
Nfun[t_] := Sum[a[[i]] Cos[f[[i]] t + ϕ[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];
Nfunc = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
Evaluate[Sum[a[[i]] Cos[f[[i]] t + ϕ[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]];

Clear[makeNfunc]
makeNfunc[a_, f_, ϕ_] := Module[{n},
n = Length[a];
Return[
 Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
  Evaluate[Sum[a[[i]] Cos[f[[i]] t + ϕ[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]]]
];
NfuncR = makeNfunc[a, f, ϕ];
```

Run the code:

```
npts = 10000;
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, npts];
Timing[Nfun[#] & /@ data;]
Timing[Nfunc[#] & /@ data;]
Timing[NfuncR[#] & /@ data;]
```

The output:

```
{0.585911, Null}
{0.012998, Null}
{0.012998, Null}
```

So in this simple case the compiled code is about 45 times faster for both the function compiled inline `Nfunc` and the function that was returned by the `makeNfunc`, `NfuncR`

So the question is what is the problem with my original function above?

Comment: I just want to add a link to an excellent package that provides a lot of $n$-space support [Obtuse Package](http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/#Obtuse) (I just need some more speed!)

Comment: `Compile` has been improved since version 7, which I use, but when I run the line `Timing[funFunc[#] & /@ xpts;]` I get ```CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression 0.` should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >>

CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 20; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>```  Do you see similar errors?

Comment: In the code as shown in the post I do not get any errors. Early on I was playing with the `rank` which gave me similar errors. I then found that 1 worked which makes since because `xi` is a vector. I get no indication that what is returned is not compiled, like the error text `proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.` implies. If I just evaluate `funFunc` I get `CompiledFunction[...stuff..]` as expected. Everything works it is just no faster.

Comment: I added an answer.  If I am correct using `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` will fix your problem.

Comment: The routine given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11883) for thin plate splines might be useful to you; you will only need to change the underlying RBF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to modify your code to get it to work without error in version 7.  Once I did it that appears to be working correctly and faster than the non-compiled code.

I needed to inject the values of `RBF` and `disfun` into the `Compile` using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html):

```
With[{iRBF = RBF, idisfun = disfun},
 If[OptionValue["Compile"], 
  Return[With[{xi = x, λi = λ, xptsi = xpts, roi = ro}, 
    Compile[{{xi, _Real, 1}}, 
     Sum[λi[[i]] iRBF[idisfun[xi, xptsi[[i]]], roi], {i, 1, 
       Length[λ]}]]]], 
  Return[Function[x, Sum[λ[[i]] iRBF[idisfun[x, xpts[[i]]], ro], {i, 1, Length[λ]}]]]]
]
```

**I believe that in later versions this can be done with:**

```
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
```

Now running your test:

```
n = 300;
d = 5;
cpts = RandomReal[{-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {n, d}];
cptab = {#, truth[#]} & /@ cpts;
xpts = #[[1]] & /@ cptab;
fundata = #[[2]] & /@ cptab;

Print["Normal Function:"];
Timing[funFun = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> False];]
Timing[funFun /@ xpts;]

Print["Compile Function:"];
Timing[funFunc = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> True];]
Timing[funFunc /@ xpts;]
i = 1;
Print["Normal function: ", funFun[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["Complie function: ", funFunc[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["The real right answer: ", fundata[[i]]];
```

> Normal Function:
>
> {0.514, Null}
>
> {0.546, Null}
>
> Compile Function:
>
> {0.515, Null}
>
> {0.094, Null}
>
> Normal function: 0.000268092
>
> Complie function: 0.000268092
>
> The real right answer: 0.000268092

Comment: Thank you I had tried many combos with `With` but I missed that one thank you.

Comment: @c186282 You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.  However, I recommend waiting 24 hours to give everyone around the world a chance to answer.  People may have even better ways to speed your code, if you give them a chance.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will toggle the answer for 24 hours. Also thank you for the edit. How did  you turn `\Pi` in the real symbol?

Comment: @c186282 One of your users provided a wonderful [browser script](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/121) that adds a button to the editor for that.  Also see [(1137)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121).

Comment: OK it has been 24 hours

Comment: @c186282 Thanks for remembering.

Answer (score 6):

The following is somewhat faster.  The principal changes are:

- The use of a distance function `Sqrt@Total[(#1-Transpose@#2)^2]&` that computes an array of distances for `disfun[x, {y1, y2,...}]` that is much faster than mapping `Norm` over individual pairs.
- The use of `Dot` instead of `Sum`.  `Dot` is much faster.  In fact, **the uncompiled function**, which is fully vectorized, **is sometimes faster** than the compiled function.
- The vectorized use of `RBF` to compute the final `Φ`, following @xzczd's example.
- The use of `LinearSolve` instead of `Inverse`, which is both faster and more numerically stable. (The maximum relative difference in the solutions was about `10^-13` to `10^-12` on a few random examples.)

Since not all distance functions and RBFs can be vectorized, some tests were added to switch to the slower point-by-point methods when the faster methods are not possible.

```
Clear[RBFInterpolationE2]

Options[RBFInterpolationE2] = {
   "DistanceFunction" -> Automatic,(*(Sqrt@Total[(#1-Transpose@#2)^2]&)=Norm[x1,#]&/@x2*)
   "RadialBasisFunction" -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2/4] &),
   "RadialScale" -> Automatic, "Debug" -> False, "Compile" -> False};

RBFInterpolationE2[cptab_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ro, xpts, fundata, Φ, disfun, λ, RBF, x, dfThreadableQ, rbfListableQ, body},
   xpts = #[[1]] & /@ cptab;
   fundata = #[[2]] & /@ cptab;
   disfun = OptionValue["DistanceFunction"];
   If[disfun === Automatic,
    disfun = Sqrt@Total[(#1 - Transpose@#2)^2] &; (* vectorized & "threadable" norm *)
    dfThreadableQ = True,
    dfThreadableQ = False  (* could add options or heuristics *)
    ];

   RBF = OptionValue["RadialBasisFunction"];
   rbfListableQ = ListQ[RBF[{0.}, 1.]];

   If[dfThreadableQ,
    (*Φ=DistanceMatrix[xpts] (* not faster for the default distance *)*)
    Φ = disfun[#, xpts] & /@ xpts,
    Φ = Table[disfun[xpts[[i]], xpts(*[[j]]*)], {i, 1, Length[xpts]}, {j, 1, Length[xpts]}]
    ];
   Which[
    OptionValue["RadialScale"] == Automatic
    , ro = Median[Flatten[Table[Drop[Φ[[i]], {i}], {i, 1, Length[Φ]}]]],
    NumberQ[OptionValue["RadialScale"]]
    , ro = OptionValue["RadialScale"],
    True
    , Print["I cannot understand \"RadialScale\"->", 
     OptionValue["RadialScale"], " So I'm going to make it up"]
    ; ro = Median[Flatten[Table[Drop[Φ[[i]], {i}], {i, 1, Length[Φ]}]]]
    ];
   If[rbfListableQ,
    Φ = RBF[Φ, ro],   (*xzczd; assumes RBF is Listable *)
    Φ = Map[RBF[#, ro] &, Φ, {2}]
    ];

   λ = LinearSolve[Φ, fundata]; (* was λ=Inverse[Φ].fundata *)

   With[{λi = λ, xptsi = xpts, roi = ro, RBFi = RBF, disfuni = disfun},
    If[dfThreadableQ, (* construct code for the interpolating function *)
     body = Hold[x, Dot[λi, RBFi[disfuni[x, xptsi], roi]]],
     body = Hold[x, Dot[λi, RBFi[disfuni[x, #] & /@ xptsi], roi]]
     ];
    If[OptionValue["Compile"],
     Return[body /. Hold[x_, code_] :>
        Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, code,
         RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]],
     Return[body /. Hold[x_, code_] :> Function[x, code]]
     ]]
   ];
```

The following shows the timings of Mr.Wizards (`W`), xzczd's (`X`) and my (`E2`) codes.

```
ClearAll[run];
run[meth_String] := Module[{ans, funFun},
   With[{RBFI = ToExpression["RBFInterpolation" <> meth]},
    <|
     "Function" -> <| 
       "Interpolation" -> First@RepeatedTiming[funFun = RBFI[cptab, "Compile" -> False]],
       "Evaluation" -> First@RepeatedTiming[ans = funFun /@ xpts],
       "RBFI" -> funFun,
       "Values" -> ans
       |>,
     "Compiled" -> <| 
       "Interpolation" -> First@RepeatedTiming[funFun = RBFI[cptab, "Compile" -> True]],
       "Evaluation" -> First@RepeatedTiming[ans = funFun /@ xpts],
       "RBFI" -> funFun,
       "Values" -> ans
       |>
     |>
    ]];


ds = Dataset[AssociationMap[run, {"W", "X", "E2"}]];
(* kinda roundabout transposing, maybe *)
Transpose[ds[[All, All, {"Interpolation", "Evaluation"}]]][[All, All, All]] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The parallelization of the compiled function is not used in the above timings.  If we use parallelization (by calling the compiled function on all points at once), the compiled function beats the uncompiled one (Mac, Intel i7, 4(8) cores):

```
funFun = ds["E2", "Compiled", "RBFI"];
First@RepeatedTiming[funFun@xpts]
(*  0.00014  *)
```

The OP compares the three methods with the OP's original code at points between the interpolation points.  All three methods do pretty well at these points.

```
With[{errdata = 
   Reap[Query[All, "Compiled", Sow@RealExponent[#Values - fundata] &]@ds][[2, 1]]},
 Histogram[
  MapThread[Legended[#, #2@Quartiles[#]] &, {errdata, Normal@Keys[ds]}],
  {1./8}, PlotRange -> {{-17, -12.5}, All}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following compares the three methods with the OP's original code at points between the interpolation points.  Mr.Wizard s code produces results that are exactly equal to the OP's. There's a small but significant error in xzczd's results, which I do not have time to explore.  The error in my results are consistent with the differences in the code, such as `LinearSolve` instead of `Inverse` (the condition number of the matrix `Φ` is around `10^5` or so on the random point sets `cptab` I checked).

```
funFun = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> True];
valsOP = funFun /@ MovingAverage[xpts, 2]; 
cfs = Query[All, "Compiled", "RBFI"]@ds // Normal // Values;
errdata2 = (Transpose[Through[cfs[#]] & /@ MovingAverage[xpts, 2] - valsOP]);

Grid@Transpose@{Normal@Keys[ds], Quartiles /@ RealExponent@errdata2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You code can be even faster. The main idea is to make use of vecterization as much as possible:

```
Clear[RBFInterpolation]

Options[RBFInterpolation] = {"DistanceFunction" -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &), 
   "RadialBasisFunction" -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2/4] &), 
   "RadialScale" -> Automatic, "Debug" -> False, "Compile" -> False};

RBFInterpolation[cptab_, opts : OptionsPattern[RBFInterpolation]] := 
  Module[{ro, xpts, fundata, Φ, disfun, λ, RBF, x}, 

   (* Modification 1 *)
   xpts = cptab\[Transpose][[1]];
   fundata = cptab\[Transpose][[2]];

   disfun = OptionValue["DistanceFunction"];
   RBF = OptionValue["RadialBasisFunction"];

   (* Modification 2 *)
   Φ = Outer[disfun, xpts, xpts, 1];

   Which[OptionValue["RadialScale"] == Automatic, 

   (* Modification 3, but this seems not to speed up much *)
    ro = With[{l = Length@Φ}, Sort[Flatten[Φ][[l + 1 ;;]]][[Ceiling[l/2]]]], 

    NumberQ[OptionValue["RadialScale"]], 
    ro = OptionValue["RadialScale"], True, 
    Print["I cannot understand \"RadialScale\"->", 
     OptionValue["RadialScale"], " So I'm going to make it up"];

    ro = With[{l = Length@Φ}, Sort[Flatten[Φ][[l + 1 ;;]]][[Ceiling[l/2]]]]];

   If[OptionValue["Debug"], Print["ro=", ro]];
   If[OptionValue["Debug"], 
    Print["Distance function on first two points"];
    Print["point 1 ->", xpts[[1]]];
    Print["point 2 ->", xpts[[2]]];
    Print["Distance ->", disfun[xpts[[1]], xpts[[2]]]];
    Print["Radial Basis Function on Distance ->", 
     RBF[disfun[xpts[[1]], xpts[[2]]], ro]]];

   (* Modification 4 *)
   Φ = RBF[Φ, ro];

   If[OptionValue["Debug"], 
    Print["Element of Φ[[1,1]]=", Φ[[1, 1]]]];
   λ = Inverse[Φ].fundata;
   If[OptionValue["Debug"], 
    Print["First element of λ[[1]]=", λ[[i]]]];

   (* Modification 5 *)
   With[{iRBF = RBF, idisfun = disfun}, 
    If[OptionValue["Compile"], 
     With[{xi = x, λi = λ, xptsi = xpts, roi = ro}, 
      Compile[{{xi, _Real, 1}}, Total[λi iRBF[idisfun[xi, #] & /@ xptsi, roi]]]], 
      Function[x, Total[λ iRBF[idisfun[x, #] & /@ xpts, ro]]]]]];
```

Notice that **Modification 4** and **5** requires `"RadialBasisFunction"` to be `Listable`, which is true for most arithmetic function. You may want to add some protective code (or use `Map` instead if you don't want to take the risk) in these parts.

Let's try your test:

```
Clear[truth]
truth[x_] := Product[Sin[x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}];

n = 300;
d = 5;
cpts = RandomReal[{-π/2, π/2}, {n, d}];

cptab = {#, truth[#]} & /@ cpts;
xpts = #[[1]] & /@ cptab;
fundata = #[[2]] & /@ cptab;

Print["Normal Function:"];
Timing[funFun = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> False];]
Timing[funFun /@ xpts;]

Print["Compile Function:"];
Timing[funFunc = RBFInterpolation[cptab, "Compile" -> True];]
Timing[funFunc /@ xpts;]
i = 1;
Print["Normal function: ", funFun[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["Complie function: ", funFunc[xpts[[i]]]];
Print["The real right answer: ", fundata[[i]]];
```

[image]

For comparison, the following is the timing of Mr.Wizard's code on my machine:

[image]