# Solving PDE with Condition on Inside of Region

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to figure out how to use NDSolve to numerically solve PDEs where some internal values may be specified on the region of the solution. An example, which I picked from a textbook, is solving Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 f = 0$ on a region where we have Dirichlet boundary conditions on each edge, but we also have this set of points inside the region where $f = 0$.

[image]

In this particular case, what I would try would be to solve over each of the two halves of the box (left and right), and ensure that $f$ and $\nabla f$ are continuous over the boundary between the halves, but as you can imagine, not every problem is so symmetrical. If I use DirichletCondition to try to specify values on the interior of the region, NDSolve ignores the interior condition. Does anybody know a better way to do this?

Edit: My first guess as to how I should code this is as follows:

```
f[x_, y_] = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0, 
 u[x, 1] == 100, u[0, y] == 100 y, u[1, y] == 100 y, 
 DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 1/2 && y <= 2/5]}, 
 u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}][x, y]
```

But the contour plot of this solution looks like this:

[image]

So NDSolve is clearly ignoring the internal condition.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You mention, *" If I use DirichletCondition to try to specify values on the interior of the region, NDSolve ignores the interior condition"* which suggests that you have already done some coding. Can you share that so folks can provide concrete suggestions?

Comment: Sure! I added the code and a plot of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually figured out how to do this myself from reading the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71902/least-effort-to-handle-a-point-source-inside-the-domain-of-pdes) and then asking [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73914/join-two-element-meshes) how to construct the mesh I was looking for. I ran the following:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
 "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {.5, 0},
  {.5,1}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4},
  {4, 1}, {5, 6}}]}]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005]
f[x_, y_] = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, u[x, 1] == 100, 
 u[x, 0] == 0, u[1, y] == 100 y, u[0, y] == 100 y, 
 DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 1/2 && y <= 2/5]}, 
 u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh][x, y]
```

...which gave me this solution:

[image]

Credit goes to the original answerers of those questions for helping me figure this out. Thanks, guys!