# Join Two Element Meshes

Tags: regions, mesh, finite-element-method

Let's say I have two element meshes defined as the following:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
a = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1/2 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]]
b = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[1/2 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]]
```

Is there any way I can construct a mesh that is the union of these two sets of mesh elements? I haven't been able to find any such commands in the documentation, but I'd like to be able to construct "boundaries" on the inside of my mesh region (in this case, a vertical line at $x = 1/2$).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RegionPlot` can find boundaries between implicit regions even with a small number of `PlotPoints`. For example, you have 4 implicit regions

```
ineqs = {-2 <= x <= 0 && -2 <= y <= 2 && x^2 + y^2 >= 1, 
   x <= 0 && x^2 + y^2 <= 1, x >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 <= 1, 
   0 <= x <= 2 && -2 <= y <= 2 && x^2 + y^2 >= 1};

r = RegionPlot[ineqs, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

Then you can construct boundary mesh. Sometimes `RegionPlot` produces small numerical errors so I use `Round[#, 0.001]` to "glue" identical points. By default, `ToBoundaryMesh` have option `"DeleteDuplicateCoordinates" -> True` so vertices with the same coordinates will be reduced to one vertex.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Round[#, 0.001] &@
    First@Cases[r, GraphicsComplex[v_, ___] :> v, ∞], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> Cases[r, Line[p_, ___] :> LineElement@Partition[p, 2, 1], ∞]];
bmesh@"Wireframe"
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you?

As I understood, your goal was a boundary in the middle of the region.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {.5, 0}, {.5, 1}}, 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}}]}]

bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks great, and that's exactly the output I wanted! I'm wondering whether there's a way to automate this for more complicated regions, though.

Comment: @MichaelLee What exactly do you mean by automating it?  You mean join two regions and include the original boundaries in the output, as you originally described the question?  (Sorry, I don't know off-hand how to do that.)

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I meant. Ideally, I'd be able to specify two parametric regions that share a boundary, and then create a single mesh from those two regions that includes the boundary.