# Difficulty in getting correct Gaussian curve for diffusion of point source

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I want to solve diffusion of a point source numerically and check it
against analytical solution. first I define initial profile,

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
deltaPos = 0;
InitComp = 100;
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < deltaPos}, {100, x == deltaPos}, {0, 
    x > deltaPos}}]
```

and the solve the differential equation,

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] - 0.2 D[D[u[x, t], {x, 1}], {x, 1}] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{pde, u[x, 0] == g[x], u[-10, t] == 0, u[10, t] ==0}, 
   u[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

Now, I expect that total mass of the system is essentially conserved, since
diffusion is yet to reach boundary points. Initial mass of the system is

```
NIntegrate[u[x, t] /. sol /. {t -> 0}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

which outputs $0$, which is acceptable since total mass is concentrated at a single point. Now to check mass after some time(essentially any time t=0.0001,0.1,1,10),

```
NIntegrate[u[x, t] /. sol /. {t -> 1}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

outputs to $0.2$, which is confusing. I think integration should produce $100$, which is the total initial mass of the system.

Analytical solution after time t is (with $ D = 0.2, C_0 = 100$),
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x,t) = \frac{C_0}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Comparing the results with analytical solution,

```
AnaS[x_] := 100*Exp[-x*x/(4*0.2*10)]/(Sqrt[4*3.14159265*0.2*10])
Plot[AnaS[x], {x, -10, 10}]
Plot[u[x, t] /. sol /. {t -> 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

tells that numerical solution is off by exactly factor of $500$. 
What am I missing here? Also another question regarding the boundary conditions. How can set boundary conditions like $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$ at the boundaries? I tried

```
D[u[10,t],x]==0
```

but it did not work.

Comment: I don't think your way of defining a point source is correct. The peak has a finite height but a width of zero, so it basically contains nothing.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I know in c++, this way of defining point source  works just fine. I am not sure with Mathematica.

Comment: You mean: "a program you know, that has been written in C++, works in a way that it can handle peaks in the way you defined", right? You realize that that has nothing to do with C++ itself, do you?

Comment: I meant any code using finite difference method to solve the differential equation should be able to handle the pick in the way defined above as intended. Nothing specific to C++, but I do not know how Mathematica handles this.

Comment: Your `InitComp` parameter is never used. The factor 500 is 100/0.2.

Comment: @bobthechemist, for $n$ dimensions, coefficient before exponential function is $\frac{1}{(4\pi D t)^{n/2}}$. here $n=1$

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71945/1871

Comment: the boundary conditions for `x=-10` and `x=10` are completely invalid. A peculiarity of the diffusion equation is that perturbations propagate instantaneously. Another thing is the way, your "delta-function" is defined. `NDSolve` gives an message that it is looking at 10000 grid points for x. The interval for x is `{-10,10}` thus it might mistakenly interpret the single point of `g[x]=100` as a peak of width around 0.002 and height up to 100 giving a total mass of around 0.2 (500 smaller than the desired 100. If I increase the x range to `{-20,20}` the solution becomes twice as large.

Comment: @alekhine, *I meant any code using finite difference method *. This requires, that a) deltaPos is among the sampling points, b) the effective mass you'll get is dependent on the density of the sampling points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you get a factor of 500 of I have explained in my comment. Let's replace your `g` with a better behaved function:

```
mass = 100;
width = 10^-2;
g[x_] := mass/width HeavisideLambda[x/width]
```

This is a triangular peak with area 100 and basewidth 0.01.

Now let's impose the desired boundary conditions of $\partial u / \partial x =0$ at the boundaries:

```
Derivative[1, 0][u][-10, t] == 0
Derivative[1, 0][u][10, t] == 0
```

Now back to your code:

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] - 0.2 D[D[u[x, t], {x, 1}], {x, 1}] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{pde, u[x, 0] == g[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][-10, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][10, t] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

This will of course complain due to the absence of a continuous derivative (much less, a continuous second derivative) of `g[x]`, but it will come up with something.

```
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

> [image: Initial conditions]
>
> Huge peak at the beginning (just a finite approximation of a delta-function).

```
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

> [image: Development]
>
> Something saner, as diffusion takes place.

`{-10, 10}` is quite a large box. It's hard to see, that the process of diffusion is really contained within it. Let's confine the region a bit and give more time to develop.

```
sol = NDSolve[{pde, u[x, 0] == g[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][-3, t] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0][u][3, t] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, 30}]
```

> [image: Levelling off]
>
> Now the peak fills the box up to about 15.

```
NIntegrate[u[x, t] /. (First@sol) /. t -> 0, {x, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

> `100.08`

I've chosen this range, because at `t=0` the peak is a bit narrow and NIntegrate can miss it.

Let's check, how everything evolves with time:

```
Do[Print[NIntegrate[u[x, t] /. (First@sol) /. t -> tt, {x, -3, 3}]],
   {tt, {1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40}}]
```

> 100.08
>   100.08
>   100.08
>   100.08
>   100.08
>   100.08

Very consistent. But I don't like the `0.08` error. Let's try to make `NDSolve`'s job a bit easier by specifying easier initial conditions (broader peak, so numerical precision isn't so much of an issue).

```
mass = 100;
width = 1;
g[x_] := mass /width HeavisideLambda[x/width]
sol = NDSolve[{pde, u[x, 0] == g[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][-3, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][3, t] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 50}]
Do[Print[NIntegrate[u[x, t] /. (First@sol) /. t -> tt, {x, -3, 3}]],
   {tt, {1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40}}]
```

> `100.`
>   `100.`
>   `100.`
>   `100.`
>   `100.`
>   `100.`

**EDIT** follow-up for ill-defined peak functions :-)

```
Clear[g]; deltaPos = 0; 
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < deltaPos}, {100, x == deltaPos}, {0, x > deltaPos}}]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] - 0.2 D[D[u[x, t], {x, 1}], {x, 1}] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{pde, u[x, 0] == g[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][-10, t] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0][u][10, t] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0.1, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

produces this (below), as `x=0` is included in the *initial* sampling points.

> [image: Lucky us]

Naturally, `NDSolve` complains about reaching the maximum of allowed grid points, because it detects a peak in `g[x]`, but can't get a handle on how narrow it is:

> NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 10000 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.

```
Clear[g]; deltaPos = 2; 
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < deltaPos}, {100, x == deltaPos}, {0, x > deltaPos}}]
```

With a definition like above `NDSolve` shuts up and returns `u[x, t]` that is zero across the domain. The initial sampling grid seems to be rather coarse. It simply doesn't realize, that there's an out-of-place peak in your starting function. `deltaPos = 5` is, however, among the sampling points. That returns a much saner result, similar to what we get for `deltaPos = 0`. The lesson to learn is "define your point sources properly".

Thanks for asking the question, it brought a great deal about solving ODEs with Mathematica to my attention, especially in the linked question in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the useful comments and full explanation..!