# How should I define the boundary conditions of free end and fixed end scenarios for 1D Wave Equation?

Tags: finite-element-method, physics, boundary-conditions, wave-equation, wave-propagation

The 1D wave equation is $$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$$
where $c$ is the wave speed, $c^2=E/\rho$, $E$ is the Young's modulus and $\rho$ is the density of the material. See the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Stress_pulse_in_a_bar).
I want to analyze the physics in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMJrtheQfZw&list=PLSzXC_pGQjWZaf0AzQkWQ-_ADBPmobiuS&index=22) of longitudinal wave.
When a mass impacts one end of a long rod with the material properties of $E$ and $\rho$ at $x=0$, longitudinal waves will be generated. Please note the $\textbf{initial conditions}$: $$v(x,t)=\dot{u}(x,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=0$$
where $v(x,t)$ represents the particle velocity in the medium. The $u(x,t)$ should be zero at time $t=0$.

Note that for any given time $0<t_1< L/c$, the longitudinal waves will travel to $$x_1=c\cdot t_1$$ For $x\geq x_1$, it is required that $$v(x,t_1)=0$$ $$u(x,t_1)=0$$
The waves will travel through the rod to the other end. Assume the length of the rod is $L$. The wave speed is $c$. At time $t=L/c$ the waves will reach $x=L$. Depending on the conditions and the other end, the waves can change and then be reflected.

1. Free end condition. That is to say, there is nothing in contact with the other end (That is $x=L$). The particle in the medium can move in the free end. What will happen when the wave reaches there?
2. Fixed end condition. In this condition, the particles in the medium at the fixed end cannot move. The particle velocity in the fixed end is strictly zero when the waves travel $x=L$. What will happen in the fixed end?

How should I analyze the two case scenarios for the 1D wave equation in Mathematica? I want to see how $u(x,t)$ will vary over $t$ and $x$.

Thank you very much!

Edited on 10/07/2022:
Using the solution from [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann), the following animation presents the results.I have a question. Why will the $u(x,t)$ increase over time? I did not expect that.

[image: Solution by Ulrich]

Comment: I'm afraid your b.c. at $x=0$ isn't a proper modeling for the scene in the video, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71945/1871 Something like $u(0,t)=\sin ^{30}(t)$ (this is just an example) may be a better choice.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html) for various boundary conditions and examples for the wave equation

Comment: You significantly changed your question without notification! My answer still describes the wave for the original problem `u[0,t]==0, Derivative[0,1][u][x,t]==0 and impact at x==0`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks for your help. Is you current solution applicable for the free end condition? What will be appropriate boundary condition for fixed end condition?

Comment: @fhk Yes it is with free end condition. Inside `NDSolveValu[...]` you'll find the condition `(*u[t,1]\[Equal]0,*)` for fixed end. Remove comment and you get solution for fixed end.

Comment: @fhk With free end condition the impact must lead to a movement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you are considering a rod, with an

impact `Derivative[0,1][u][t,0]==DiracDelte[t]`  at `x==0`

and

boundary condition `u[t,1]==0 or Derivative[0,1][u][t,1]==0` at `x==1`!

Analytical solution might be described using `GreenFunction` , unfortunately Mathematica doesn't solve.

Remains the numerical solution:

The impact should be modelled by a numerical approximation `UnitTriangle[t/(eps/2) - 1] (2/eps),eps<<1`  of the DiracDelta -function. Additionally I introduced a small damping to smooth simulation results.

For the free end condition `Derivative[ 0, 1][u][t, 1]==0` try

```
eps = 1/10 ;
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][u][t, x] -Derivative[ 0, 2][u][t, x] + 2 /100 Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] == 
UnitTriangle[t/(eps/2) - 1] 2/eps NeumannValue[1, x ==0],(*u[t,1]\[Equal]0,*)Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[0, x] == 0}, 
u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1}   , 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" ,"MeshOptions"-> { "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/50} }}  , MaxStepSize -> eps/10]

Plot3D[Evaluate[ U[t, x]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5} , PlotPoints ->100,MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Plot shows the waves for differnt times and also the global movement of the free rod !

Add `u[t,1]==0` for the second end condition.

**addendum fixed end**

```
eps = 1/10 ; tsim = 5;
Uf = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][u][t, x] - 
     Derivative[ 0, 2][u][t, x] + 
     2  10^-2 Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] == 
    UnitTriangle[t/(eps/2) - 1] 2/eps NeumannValue[1, x == 0],  
   u[t, 1] == 0,   
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[0, x] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}   , 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" , 
      "MeshOptions" -> { "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/50} }}  , 
  MaxStepSize -> eps/10]

  list = Table[Plot[Uf[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t,Subdivide[0, tsim, 100]}];
  ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Can you explain the coefficients in the PDE? In NDSolveValue[], you define the PDE. 1. What does "2/100" mean in the PDE? 2. If I want to specify an initial particle velocity at x==0, how should I do? 3. Why does we still need some coefficient in the right hand side of the PDE?

Comment: @fhk Righthandside describes the impact and `2 /100 Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] ` is a small damping

Comment: @fhk You need to know  velocity and mass of the particle

Comment: The boundary condition for free end $u_x(t,x)=0$ was not enforced at $x=1$. I do not see '''Derivative[0,1][u][t,1]==0 at x==1!''' in your code. It still produces the results.

Comment: @fhk Condition for free end is implicitly included in the first part of  my answer. You could add an  additional `NeumannValue[0, x ==1]`

Comment: On the RHS of PDE, you use Neumann B.C. to define the impulse. The Neumann B.C. is essentially $u_x(t,x)$. 1. How is Neumann B.C related to a given velocity $v_0$ or a given force $f$ at $x=0$?  2. Can you provide a reference about the B.C. or I.C. for wave equation? I would like to learn more about it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is the advantage of introducing a damping component in the system?

Comment: One more question: After $U(t,x)$ is obtained, how can I evaluate the time derivative to get $U_t(t,x)$? Thanks.

Comment: `Derivative[1,0][U][t,x]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I input a initial velocity $v_0$ at $x=0$ as one of the initial conditions?

Comment: @fhk The initial velocity depends on the size of factor of `UnitTriangle[t/(eps/2) - 1] 2/eps`. Actual setting `1` leads to a velocity  `1` of the rod. Probably the factor equals `v0`!

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect solution for the fixed end condition where $u(L,t)=0$:

define some parameters:

```
c = 500;
L = 5;
t0 = 0.1;
U = NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] == c^2 D[u[t, x], {x, 2}],
   u[0, x] == 0,
   u[t, 0] == Sin[80 \[Pi] t],
   u[t, L] == 0},
  u, {t, 0, t0}, {x, 0, L}]
```

Show the results:

```
list = Table[
   Plot[U[t, x], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, t0, 0.003}];
ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]

Comment: An impact at `x==0&&t==0` causes a wave, starting from `x==0` and travelling in positive x-direction. Your "solution" doesn't show this effect!

Comment: I agree well. Please propose some initial conditions or boundary conditions. How should we fix this problem?

Comment: See my answer including the Boundaryconditions and `NeumannValue` !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).