# Understanding polyharmonic splines

Tags: matrix, splines

[Rahul Narain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul-narain) and [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/%ef%bc%aa-%ef%bc%ad) gives implementation of the thin plate polyharmonic splines in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11883/484). Rahul Narain's method is clear. J.M.'s is convenient to reuse. But J.M. used too many matrix(ls,ws,lx,bb,etc.) that I cannot follow his idea. Who can tell me what's the meaning of the last three lines of coding?

```
ls = LinearSolve[Φ[N[Function[point, Apply[Abs[#1 + I #2] &, point - tx]] /@ xa,
                         Precision[data]]]];
ws = ls[wa]; lx = ls[xap];
xap = Transpose[xap]; bb = LinearSolve[xap.lx, xap.ws];
(ws - lx.bb).Φ[EuclideanDistance[vars, #] & /@ xa] + bb.Append[vars, 1]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, OP did not even try to read [the answer I linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2748) in my previous answer.

In any event: I merely exploited the block structure of the underlying linear system for the polyharmonic spline.

We start with `data` looking like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\&\vdots&\\x_n&y_n&z_n\end{pmatrix}$$

```
wa = data[[All, -1]];
xa = Drop[data, None, -1];
```

This results in

$$\mathtt{xa = }\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2\\\vdots&\\x_n&y_n\end{pmatrix}\quad \mathtt{wa = }\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\\vdots\\z_n\end{pmatrix}$$

```
xap = PadRight[xa, {n, p}, 1];
```

$$\mathtt{xap}=\mathbf W=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\&\vdots&\\x_n&y_n&1\end{pmatrix}$$

```
ls = LinearSolve[Φ[N[Function[point, Sqrt[Total[(point - tx)^2]]] /@ xa,
                              Precision[data]]]];
```

I actually did two things at once here. First, I formed the matrix of RBFs:

$$\mathbf A=\small \begin{pmatrix}0&\phi(\|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|)&\cdots&\phi(\|(x_1,y_1)-(x_n,y_n)\|)\\\phi(\|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|)&0&&\vdots\\\vdots&&\ddots&\\\phi(\|(x_1,y_1)-(x_n,y_n)\|)&\cdots&&0\end{pmatrix}$$

and then precomputed the LU decomposition as `ls` for later use. (I used this construction instead of `Outer[]`, per [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21863).)

Now, we have to solve the block linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf A&\mathbf W\\\mathbf W^\top&\mathbf 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\\mathtt{bb}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathtt{wa}\\\mathbf 0\end{pmatrix}$$

```
ws = ls[wa]; lx = ls[xap];
```

We then have $\mathtt{ws}=\mathbf A^{-1}\mathtt{wa}$ and $\mathtt{lx}=\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf W$.

```
xap = Transpose[xap]; bb = LinearSolve[xap.lx, xap.ws];
```

We now have $\mathtt{xap}=\mathbf W^\top$, and then we solve the linear system $\mathbf W^\top\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf W\cdot\mathtt{bb}=\mathbf W^\top\mathbf A^{-1}\mathtt{wa}$. (Again, refer to the math.SE answer on how these expressions were derived.)

Finally, $\mathbf v=$ `ws - lx.bb` is just $\mathbf A^{-1}\mathtt{wa}-\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf W\cdot\mathtt{bb}$, and we now form the polyharmonic spline function from the derived coefficients.

Comment: I have followed your link and am unable to get from one particular step to another. I am posting an answer below to show where I am stuck. I will delete the answer after I have an understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble following the step going from

[image]

to

[image]

Thanks to J.M. for helping me through the steps.

I thought other users might find the following breakdown helpful.

**Step 1. Multiply both sides by the inverse**

[image]

**Step 2. Apply matrix inversion by parts**

J.M. shows how to compute matrix inversion by parts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/solving-very-large-matrices-in-pieces/2748#2748).

[image]

**Step 3. Simplify the bottom row**

Since we now have a vector on each side of the equality we can equate and simplify the bottom row

[image]

**Step 4. Equate and simplify the top row**

In the simplification here the right hand side of the first equation in step three is replaced with `bb`.

[image]

QED

Comment: You're supposed to multiply the expression for the partitioned inverse with $\begin{pmatrix}\bf \tt{wa}\\\mathbf 0\end{pmatrix}$, thus resulting in expressions for $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\\bf \tt{bb}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. I think I got it now.

Comment: Looks right to me. :)