# Continuous partial derivative of an interpolated function

Tags: interpolation

I know the values for a function v[x,y] on an irregular grid of (x,y) points.  Call the table storing all these points xyvtriples.  Because of the irregular grid, the Mathematica function Interpolation only works as

`interpolatedvfunc = Interpolation[xyvtriples, InterpolationOrder -> 1];`

But what I really need are the partial derivatives of interpolatedfunc with respect to each argument, and for those partials to be continuous, which won't happen due to the edges produced by InterpolatioOrder -> 1.

Is there any way around this?  I can make a very fine grid of (x,y) points to (I hope) counter any problems with forcing a spline like interpolation if I can somehow force this to happen.

Thanks.

Comment: If `NDSolve` can do it, you can, too: (E.g. `usol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]; Plot3D[Evaluate[D[u[x, y], x] /. First[usol]], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]`.  But I don't understand your setup/workflow and feel it's not worth trying something out I don't really need and don't know if it will help. Please give a minimal working example (in code) for us to copy/paste and play with.

Comment: You say that you can make a very fine grid of $(x,y)$ points; what, then, is stopping you from making this fine grid so regular that `Interpolation` will accept it at higher order?

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you tell us how you calculate the values of your $v(x,y)$, then maybe somebody can suggest a direct way of calculating the partial derivatives instead of taking a detour over interpolation and numerical differentiation.

Comment: You might also use [`polyharmonicSpline[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11883/4999).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the first interpolation to create data on a grid. Then you can interpolate this new data with the default InterpolationOrder->3. Here is an example:

f1 = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Plot3D[f1[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]

[image]

Now we can create new data and interpolate it:

dat2 = Table[{x, y, f1[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
f2 = Interpolation[dat];
Plot3D[f2[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]

[image]

Finally you can get the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

> I can make a very fine grid of (x,y) points to (I hope)...

*I* hope to have guessed the OP's setup/workflow...and that this quote indicates that the data/function to be interpolated can be generated for any set of points.

In which case, we can use a quadratic `ElementMesh[]` to get a higher-order interpolation.

```
Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`";
emesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
data = Function[{x, y}, Sin[3 x] Cos[2 y]^2] @@@ 
   emesh["Coordinates"]; (* need data pt for each of these coords *)
ifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, data];
Plot3D[Evaluate[D[ifn[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, y} \[Element] emesh]
```

[image]

Being order 2, `ifn` is not of class $C^2$:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[D[ifn[x, y], {x, 2}]], {x, y} \[Element] emesh, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, NormalsFunction -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]