# Specialized form of Outer[f, list, list] for symmetric f

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

Consider a function `f` that is symmetric with regard to its two arguments i.e. `f[x,y] == f[y,x]`. Using `Outer` one can for instance build a correspondence matrix that computes some distance measure `f` between each two points in a list using

```
Outer[f, list, list]
```

This however computes every entry `f[i, j]` literally twice (since `f[i, j] == f[j, i]`) which is unnecessary. Is there a way to beat `Outer` (which is quite fast already) using this knowledge?

I tried

```
Table[Plus[list[[i]], list[[j]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}, {j, i, Length[list]}]
```

which only computes each entry once but is orders of magnitude slower even for simple examples like `f = Plus; list = Range[1000]`.

Comment: It makes no sense to have an iterator `{I, list}`, since list is a `List` and not an integer.  Perhaps you mean `Length[list]`.  If you want to use `Table`, then try:  `Table[f[I,j], {I, Length[list},{I,j}]` to compute the unique values, and then fill in the rest with a simple Table call.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `Table[expr, {i, {i1, i2, i3, ...}}]` and thus `Table[expr_, {i, someList}]` is a valid syntax variant for `Table`. Its the 5th entry in the syntax overview in the documentation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Never mind, I only tried the `Table` variant with input like `list=Range[10]` and for this the Part specification works out.

Comment: Fixed the issue with the `Table` expression in the question

Comment: `Plus` is special in a number of way; and `Outer[Plus,...]` is a special case. It might not be a good test example?

Comment: When working with symmetric arrays, it may be useful to consider SymmetrizedArray, particularly in cases with high symmetry (with deep arrays). You may use SymmetrizedArray as constructor, or you can use standard array methods and then use Symmetrize to produce SymmetrizedArray results. This may also help in case in which storage space is important, because SymmetrizedArray only keeps one copy of each independent element.

Answer (score 6):

`Outer[Plus,...]` is a special case that is very fast.  It's not a good example to compare with `Table`.  I'm not sure what assumptions one might make about `f`, which might lead to particular optimizations, but I'll pick `Norm`. It's neither `Listable` nor compilable.  The half `Table` saves some time over `Outer`:

```
list = Range[1., 1000.];

m1 = Outer[Norm@*List, list, list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.31615, Null}  *)

Table[Norm[{list[[i]], list[[j]]}], {i, 1, Length[list]}, {j, i, 
    Length[list]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.18397, Null}  *)
```

Here are a couple of ways to fill out the rest of the array inspired by 
[Best way to create symmetric matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/best-way-to-create-symmetric-matrices)
and
[Generating random symmetric matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59679/generating-random-symmetric-matrix):

```
(mat = PadLeft[
     Table[
      Norm[{list[[i]], list[[j]]}], {i, 1, Length[list]}, {j, i, 
       Length[list]}],
     Automatic, 0.];
   m2 = mat + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.32359, Null}  *)

(upper = Flatten[
     Table[
      Norm[{list[[i]], list[[j]]}], {i, 1, Length[list]}, {j, i + 1, Length[list]}]];
   diag = Table[Norm[{x, x}], {x, list}];
   m3 = Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[upper, diag, Length@list]
); // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.22123, Null}  *)

m1 == m2 == m3
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: You can also use `Sqrt@Outer[Plus, #, #] &[list^2]`

Answer (score 5):

For such a simple thing like `Plus`, I can beat `Outer` on my quad core CPU by a factor of 2 with

```
cf1 = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real, 1}},
    Table[a + b[[i]], {i, 1, Length[b]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

We can do this for the upper triangular part of the output matrix in a similar fashion with

```
cf2 = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real, 1}, {i, _Integer}},
    Table[a + b[[j]], {j, i, Length[b]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Here are the timings:

```
n = 10000;
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];
r0 = Outer[Plus, list, list]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 = cf1[list, list]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = cf2[list, list, Range[n]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r0 == r1

0.513

0.20

0.11

True
```

Indeed, `cf2` is faster than `cf1` by almost a factor of 2 (as expected). However, note that `cf2` produces a ragged list of lists and not a square array. Getting this back into a square matrix is not that inexpensive. So it may be still be a good idea to compute some entries of the output twice. Note that often (and in particular in this case) it is not the floating point computation that limits the execution speed; it is memory access.

Answer (score 0):

The very first lines of the question bring to mind the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute.

> "...Consider a function `f` that is symmetric with regard to its two arguments i.e. `f[x,y] == f[y,x]`"

One possible way to overcome the problem reported below

> "...This however computes every entry `f[i, j]` literally twice (since `f[i, j] == f[j, i]`)"

might be to [*memoize*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/8617#8617) the function `f`

```
ClearAll[f,g]
SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
f[x__] := f[x] = g[x]
```

where `g[]` stands for an appropriate expression for `f`.

Consider the following example:

```
i = 1;
g[x__] := (Print[i]; i += 1; h[x])
list = {1, 2, 3}
Outer[g, list, list, 1]
```

Evaluation of that, will print numbers `1` through `9` and then return

> `{{h[1, 1], h[1, 2], h[1, 3]}, {h[2, 1], h[2, 2], h[2, 3]}, {h[3, 1], h[3, 2], h[3, 3]}}`

If, on the other hand, we were to evaluate

```
i = 1;
Outer[f, list, list, 1]
```

then, the output we'd receive, would be

> `{{h[1, 1], h[1, 2], h[1, 3]}, {h[1, 2], h[2, 2], h[2, 3]}, {h[1, 3], h[2, 3], h[3, 3]}}`

after printing numbers `1` through `6`.

Please note that if you evaluate *this* last example code once more, nothing will get printed and the result will be the same as it was after the first evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Without any attribute `Outer[g, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]` yields

```
 {{h[1, 1], h[1, 2], h[1, 3]}, {h[2, 1], h[2, 2], h[2, 3]}, {h[3, 1], h[3, 2], h[3, 3]}}
```

Using a pure function with the `Orderless` attribute:

```
g = Function[{x, y}, h[x, y], Orderless]
```

we get

```
Outer[g, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]

{{h[1, 1], h[1, 2], h[1, 3]}, {h[1, 2], h[2, 2], h[2, 3]}, {h[1, 3], h[2, 3], h[3, 3]}}
```

Hence, if the code for `h` is efficient, so is the application of `Outer`.