# Fast method to calculating signature of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, eigenvalues

For calculation of the topological properties of a hamiltonian, sometimes we need the signature of that matrix. This means we only need number of positive eigenvalues. One simple way is to first calculate the eigenvalues and then find difference of number of positive and negative eigenvalues.  for example,

```
H = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}] // (# + #\[ConjugateTranspose]) &;
Total[If[# > 0, 1, -1] & /@ Eigenvalues[H]]
```

I am interested to know i) is there any function in Mathematica calculate signature ii) is there any fast algorithm within Mathematica to do so fast?

Comment: You mean `Sign`? This function is `Listable` i.e. `Sign[{-3, 4, 0}]` works BTW.

Comment: `Total@Sign@Eigenvalues[H]`

Comment: The problem is not in sign. The problem is how to get rids of the eigenvalue calculation.

Comment: @Rasoul-Ghadimi First of all, there's no function in *Mathematica* that directly computes the signature of a matrix. Furthermore, all the definitions for *signature* I can find lead to eigenvalues. Unless there're definitions that avoid eigenvalues (e.g. ask on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)), I don't think there's any faster way to do the calculation.

Comment: Related:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107593/computing-signature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
H = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}] // (# + #\[ConjugateTranspose]) &;
Short[H, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1.269557961,-0.6813805661,<<96>>,-0.3068229219,-0.9273213366},<<98>>,{-<<19>>,<<99>>}}
> ```

## Comparison

`Eigenvalues` is the fastest:

```
Total@Sign@Eigenvalues[H] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00044, 2}
> ```

[Descartes' Sign Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html) on the characteristic polynomial:

```
Total[1 - Ratios[Sign@CoefficientList[
       CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], x]
     ]] - MatrixRank[H] // RepeatedTiming

Total[RealAbs@Differences@Sign@CoefficientList[
       CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], x]] - 
  MatrixRank[H] // RepeatedTiming

2 (Length[Split@Sign@CoefficientList[
         CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], x]
      ] - 1) - MatrixRank[H] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0030, 2}
> {0.0031, 2}
> {0.0032, 2}
> ```

$LDL^\top$ decomposition ([idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/507841/654489), [code from @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92502/69875)):

```
Total@Sign@LDLT[H][[2]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0036, 2}
> ```

### Benchmark

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
BenchmarkPlot[{sig1Eigen, sig2Poly1Ratio, sig2Poly2Diff, 
  sig2Poly3Split, sig3LDLT},
 n \[Function] Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[
     #[[n + 1 ;;]], #[[;; n]], n
     ] &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Binomial[n + 1, 2]],
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 100]
```

Definitions are the same as above. (Here real symmetric matrices are generated with an undocumented function seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102795/69875), which is *a bit* faster.) Result:

[image: Benchmark for Matrix Signatures]

It seems that all of these methods are in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ (`Ratios` one should be the same), but `Eigenvalues` one has the smallest coefficient.

### Note: Bug?

One strange thing is that `CountRoots` doesn't give correct answers here, nor does `Reduce` or `Solve`. Is this a bug?

```
CountRoots[CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

> ```
> 21 (* Should be 51 *)
> ```

```
Reduce[CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x] == 0 && x > 0, x] // Length (* or Solve *)
```

> ```
> 15 (* Should be 51 *)
> ```

```
Solve[{CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x] == 0, x > 0}, x, 
  Complexes] // Length
```

> ```
> 51 (* Correct *)
> ```

```
Reduce[CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x] == 0, x] // Length (* or Solve *)
```

> ```
> 100 (* Correct *)
> ```

Otherwise, `2 CountRoots[CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] - MatrixRank[H]` can be used.

#### Update

This must be a bug -- Some real-valued roots are considered by `CountRoots` to have "invisible" imaginary parts, with some of them "$| Im(x) | \gt 1$"!

```
CountRoots[
  CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], {x, -I, 100 + I}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {44.9898317, 33} (* Still incorrect *)
> ```

```
CountRoots[
  CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], {x, -5 I, 
   100 + 5 I}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {127.967137, 51} (* Correct, but very slow *)
> ```

`Solve` has slighter peoblem. I think it's due to the machine precision:

```
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x] == 0 && Re[x] > 0, x] // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0206228, 51} (* Correct *)
> ```

#### Update 2

According to [@MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224981/fast-method-to-calculating-signature-of-a-matrix/224997#comment573033_224997), this is because the machine precision is not enough for the large coefficients and high degree of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the methods scale with the matrix size $n$. What method is the asymptotic winner for $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @yarchik, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Nice analysis. I interpret it as the rank-determination is the bottleneck with $\mathcal{O}(n^\omega)$.

Comment: @yarchik Yes, and also the characteristic polynomial, maybe with $\mathcal{O}\left( n^\omega \log n \right)$.

Comment: Probably not a bug. Machine-precision, high-degree polynomials are known to be [perfidious](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Wilkinson.pdf).  Examine `Plot[Evaluate@CharacteristicPolynomial[H, x], {x, 0, 10}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for the note! This is a new point for me. I had been unaware of this until I did the plot. Seems that `Eigenvalue` is the fastest *and* most reliable.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min Why did my computer freeze after I executed this code(12.1)? `Needs["GeneralUtilities\`"];
BenchmarkPlot[{sig1Eigen, sig2Poly1Ratio, sig2Poly2Diff, 
  sig2Poly3Split, sig3LDLT},
 n \[Function] Statistics\`Library\`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[
     #[[n + 1 ;;]], #[[;; n]], n
     ] &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Binomial[n + 1, 2]],
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 100]`

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: Did you define `sig1Eigen, sig2Poly1Ratio, sig2Poly2Diff, sig2Poly3Split, sig3LDLT`? And did you see `n = ...` printed? Notice that I set the option `TimeConstraint -> 100`, so every function will be benchmarked for 100 seconds. Reduce this option value to run a smaller benchmark.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min There is no specific definition of `sig1Eigen, sig2Poly1Ratio, sig2Poly2Diff...`, etc. in your answer, where should I obtain their detailed information?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: They're just `Total@Sign@Eigenvalues[H]` ... these stuff.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min Is your computer a server? Only when the `TimeConstraint `parameter is set to 0.2 and n is set to 10, my computer can output graphics.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: No, just laptop. Actually you don't need to set `n`. Try deleting the `TimeConstraint` option.