# Creat a matrix with boundary condition

Tags: tensors, expression-construction

I would creat a symmetric matrix, but how can I set the boundary in `Subscript`?

```
Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

$a_{ij} = a_{ji}$, $j$ is not equal to $i$.

Comment: may be https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/best-way-to-create-symmetric-matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Array[Subscript[a, ## & @@ Sort[{##}]] &, {5, 5}] //  MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{1,2} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{1,3} & a_{2,3} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{1,4} & a_{2,4} & a_{3,4} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{1,5} & a_{2,5} & a_{3,5} & a_{4,5} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

You can also use

```
 Array[Subscript[a, Min @ ##, Max @ ##] &, {5, 5}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  how can I get the voigt notation from second order tensor in a efficient way in Mathematica?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, i am afraid i don't know off the top of my head; that sounds like good new question.

Comment: I am also afraid that I will I get negative note if i ask such a question....

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, i happen to think that it is a good question. With a small example and a link (say, to wikipedia) it is likely to be received very well on this site.