# Calculate mean and standard deviation from ImageHistogram

Tags: image-processing, histograms

I am doing my PhD in Clinical Neuropsychology; I had someone helping me analyse images (.jpg pictures) in *Mathematica*, but it turns out this person made some really bad decisions, and well, now I have to do it myself. But, I have no idea.

Basically, what I want is to analyze the JPEG image, get a RGB histogram, and get the values for the mean and standard deviation of this histogram.

Using `ImageHistogram [[*image*], Appearance, -> "Separated"]` works fine, but I can't figure out the next step, turning the histogram plot into numbers.

How can I do that?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You could use `ImageData[]` to get the values being binned for the histograms...

Comment: Thank you for responding!!I am trying it right now!

Comment: Hmmm... it says A very large out put was generated, here is a sample of it. "{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.},"

Comment: And if I input: StandardDeviation[Out[37]] I get pretty much the same result.

Comment: You might need the `Interleaving` option...

Comment: Try something like : `image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]; data = ImageData[image]; {Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} & /@ Transpose[Flatten[data, 1]]`.

Comment: Isn't he just looking for BinCounts?

Comment: Is it necessary to to get the metrics *of the bins* or is it sufficient to get the metrics of the RGB values themselves, un-binned, as Murta's answer does?

Answer (score 7):

There is one suggestion.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
imgChannelsRGB = Transpose@Flatten[ImageData[img], 1];
```

Creating Histogram:

```
GraphicsRow[Histogram /@ imgChannelsRGB, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Geting statistics:

```
TableForm[Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[#]] & /@ imgChannelsRGB, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Red", "Blue", "Green"}, {"Mean", "StDev"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `imgChannelsRGB = Flatten /@ ImageData[img, Interleaving -> False]`. The Lenna example image is easily accessed as `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]`.

Comment: Nice tip. Changed the example.

Comment: Am trying it right now!

Comment: O wow, this is very promissing! I'm going to play with this (and then I might be back). Thnx!

Comment: You could use `ImageData[img] ~Flatten~ {{3}, {1, 2}}` in place of `Transpose@Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]`, eliminating Transpose.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Wizard, nice tip, but i think it makes the code really difficult to read. Few people understands Flatten matrix argument (explained in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument)

Comment: @Murta -- I hoped my comment would help people learn that syntax but I agree with your choice to use `Transpose` in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be interesting to combine the graphs and statistics in small multiple style, but I got stuck... How do you present two numbers as a label without showing the curly brackets?

[image: small multiple]

Code:

```
{r, g, b} = ColorSeparate[img];
Row[
 Labeled[
    ImageHistogram[#, Appearance -> "Transparent",  Joined -> False, 
     Frame -> None],
    {
     Mean[Flatten[ImageData[#]]],
     StandardDeviation[Flatten[ImageData[#]]]
     },
    ImageSize -> 200
    ] & /@ {r, g, b}
 ]
```

Edit with bill (?!)'s suggestion:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Labeled[
    ImageHistogram[#, Appearance -> "Transparent", Joined -> False, 
     Frame -> None],
    Style[
     Column[
      {
       Mean[Flatten[ImageData[#]]],
       StandardDeviation[Flatten[ImageData[#]]]
       }
      ], 
     14, Bold], 
    ImageSize -> 500
    ] & /@ {r, g, b}]
```

[image: better small multiple]

Comment: Maybe add a `Column` ? Row[Labeled[
    ImageHistogram[#, Appearance -> "Transparent", Joined -> False, 
     Frame -> None], 
    Column[{Mean[Flatten[ImageData[#]]], 
      StandardDeviation[Flatten[ImageData[#]]]}], 
    ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {r, g, b}]

Comment: @b.gatessucks Good idea! As usual, your comments are better than my answers! :)

Comment: Wow! I have been getting some help from a friend, and we will definitely come back to this!

Comment: OK, so we are on a roll, but now I have a new, buyt related qustion. Should i post it here or open a new topic?