# Using Transpose with a list as the second argument

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I'm having difficulty understanding the `Transpose` function. I know what the transpose of a matrix is, not a problem, and I see that applying the `Transpose` function to a 3×3 matrix does what is expected.

What I am having difficulty with is the definition, which says:

> `Transpose[list]`, "transpose the top two levels of list"

Consider:

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Transpose[A]
```

What does it mean when the definition says "transpose the top two levels of the list?"

I've read about levels in lists, experimented with `TreeForm`, but something like this is giving me a lot of trouble.

```
A = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, l}}}
Transpose[A, {3, 1, 2}]
```

Can someone help me (gently) understand the definition:

> `Transpose[list,{n1,n2,...}]`, "put the $k^{th}$ level in list at level $n_k$" ?

Comment: So as to not replicate the effort, please also read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/5) by Leonid, which is for `Flatten` with non-trivial second arguments. The idea is the same for `Transpose`, but the direction is reversed (i.e., it's an "inverse" operation)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's look at this with a simple example without considering complicated indexing and levels. Consider the list (the colours are merely for visual guidance):

```
A = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions@A
(* {2, 3, 4} *)
```

This is a list containing 2 lists, each of which contains 3 sublists, which in turn contain 4 elements of the array.

#### What does "top two levels" mean?

If you consider the 2 rows above as "level 1" (not related to `Level`) or the first dimension (this is a better word than "level"), the 3 columns as "level 2" or the second dimension and the 4 elements as "level 3" and so on, what the transpose operation does on this multi-dimensional array is to simply flip the rows and columns (i.e., levels 1 and 2), just like in a matrix.

```
Atrans = Transpose[A]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions@Atrans
(* {3, 2, 4} *)
```

The only difference is that in a matrix, the $(i,j)^{th}$ element is a single element, whereas here it is a list of 4 elements. Calling `Dimensions` on the above two arrays will show you that it is flipped from `{2,3,4}` to `{3,2,4}` (the third dimension is left intact).

#### How do you use the second argument of `Transpose`?

The statement "transpose the first two levels" becomes a little clearer if you consider an explicit second argument for `Transpose`:

```
Atrans == Transpose[A, {2, 1}] 
(* True *)
```

So you see that we simply swapped dimensions 2 and 1. This would then mean that if I used `{1, 2}` as the second argument, the array should be left intact:

```
A == Transpose[A, {1, 2}]
(* True *)
```

The second argument is useful when you want to do more complex swaps, like for example, $1\to3, 2\to1, 3\to 2$, which is easily expressed as:

```
Transpose[A, {3, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions@%
(* {3, 4, 2} *)
```

In other words, the 1st dimension in `A` is now the 3rd dimension in the result, the 2nd is now the 1st and the 3rd is now the 2nd, which is what is meant by "put the $k$th level in list at level $n_k$"

Comment: +1 I am thinking the illustrations might work even better with some color coding.  E.g., `colors[1, 1] = Darker[Red];
colors[1, 2] = Darker[Green];
colors[1, 3] = Darker[Blue];
colors[2, 1] = Lighter[Red];
colors[2, 2] = Lighter[Green];
colors[2, 3] = Lighter[Blue];
f[x_] := Replace[MatrixForm[x], 
   Subscript[a, i_, j_, k___] -> 
    Style[Subscript[a, i, j, k], colors[i, j]], -1];
f[A]`, etc.

Comment: Yeah! Something like this http://preschoolteachingaidsbycarolyn.com/images/Froggy%20Sums.jpg

Comment: @belisarius Shouldn't it be toads instead of frogs for this answerer?

Comment: @Jens I'm as bad in Zoology as in Math.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I've added some colour coding to the elements :)

Comment: @rm -rf If i define `A = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}]` and I do `Dimensions[Transpose[A, {3, 1, 2, 4, 5}]]` I do not get `{13,11,12,14,15}`, why?