# Is there an equivalent of "shiftdim" of MATLAB?

Tags: list-manipulation, video

Recently I'm spending my time implementing some computer vision algorithms, which usually handle a large amount of data.

The problem I'm facing now is that I have to reform my video data to pass it to `Fourier`.
To be precise, I'm trying to apply a temporal filter to video, whose dimension is **Time*X*Y*Channel**, while I want to apply `Fourier` to `video[[All, x, y, c]]` (`x`,`y`,`c` are some integers).

I've already tried to naively reform the data using `Table`. It works like charm for small data, but for large data, reforming alone takes long and consumes too much memory. (Took about 4 minutes and 3~4 GB of memory to handle data < 100 MBytes)

MATLAB's [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) sounds like a nice solution, while I failed to find an equivalent or workarounds for *Mathematica*. (Or maybe my approach is wrong?)

### In short:

> Is there any way to efficiently reform a multi-dimensional array, just like `shiftdim`?

Comment: Also make sure that your array is packed to reduce memory usage and increase performance! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16968/5

Comment: Thanks for the great advices. Now my implementation does the job in 70 seconds using less than 2 GB of memory!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An almost direct equivalent of `shiftdim` is `Transpose` with two arguments:

Say, if we have a 3-dimensional array `arr`, then `shiftdim(arr,1)` will be the same as

```
Transpose[arr, {3,1,2}]
```

More generally,

```
shiftdim[arr_, k_] := Transpose[arr, RotateRight[Range@ArrayDepth[arr], k]]
```

is completely equivalent to the MATLAB version of the function for any positive `k` (MATLAB's `shiftdim` has a different behaviour for negative `k`).