# Understanding Transpose

Tags: list-manipulation

It is very likely that it is my lack of math skills that is showing up here. However, I think `Transpose` is such an important function that I need to master it. So I am going to ask because I do not understand the information given in the documentation.

> Transpose[list,{Subscript[n, 1], Subscript[n, 2], …}] transposes list so that the k-th level in list is the Subscript[n, k]-th level in the result.

Would anyone be able to provide a simple example and point out in a matrix what is going on? I am in particular struggling with the nth and k-th level. How does that work?

I want to master `Transpose[list, {…}]`. Please explain the case where the k-th and n-th level are to be transposed, since this is where I am struggling.

If this is considered mathematical question, and therefore not in the right place, I would appreciate a comment so that I could delete the post.

Comment: There are copious examples in the `Scope` section of the function in the documentation. Look at the results (the pattern of indexes in particular) of those results, should be clear.

Comment: As a mathematical question, "What is the transpose?" is actually pretty complex. In short, it's a canonical isomorphism between $V\otimes W^*$ and $V^*\otimes W$ that exists whenever $V,W$ are Hilbert spaces.

Comment: `Transpose[$m, {3, 2, 1}] === Flatten[$m, {{3}, {2}, {1}}]`, so you might find [this discussion of Flatten](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/142) useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Transpose with a list as the second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/using-transpose-with-a-list-as-the-second-argument)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a visualization of the 3 dimensional case.  A part of the `tensor` is indexed by

```
`tensor[[l1, l2, l3]]`
```

where `l1, l2, l3` are the indices to levels 1, 2, 3 respectively.  Transposing switches how the values are indexed.  For example, if `new = Transpose[old, {2, 3, 1}]`, then `new[[l3, l1, l2]] == old[[l1, l2, l3]]` or  `new[[l1, l2, l3]] == old[[l2, l3, l1]]`.  The first equality corresponds to how the result is described in [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html).

In the visualization below, the colors are transposed according to the permutation labeling the graphics.  Level 1 corresponds to hue, level 2 to saturation, and level 3 to brightness.  The upper left is the identity permutation and corresponds to the original tensor.  The labels on the axes correspond to the level in the original tensor.

```
tensor = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}];
cf[i_, j_, k_] := Hue[(i - 1)/4, j/4, (k + 3)/9];
g[p_] := Graphics3D[{
    PointSize[0.1],
    Point[Flatten[tensor, 2], 
     VertexColors -> cf @@@ Flatten[Transpose[tensor, p], 2]]
    },
   PlotRange -> {{0.8, 4.2}, {0.8, 4.2}, {0.8, 4.2}},
   PlotLabel -> p,
   Axes -> True, Ticks -> None,
   AxesLabel -> Ordering@p
   ];

GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[g[p], {p, Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]}], 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I hope that this example will help with understanding how higher dimensional tensors are transposed.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. In your example, `new[[l3, l1, l2]] == old[[l1, l2, l3]]` or  `new[[l1, l2, l3]] == old[[l2, l3, l1]] ` , do you have an easy way to know the arrangement `{l2,l3,l1}` given `{l3,l1,l2}`? For example, I have a tensor with dimension `{l1,l2,l3,l4}`, and I want to have `new[[l2, l3, l1,l4]] == old[[l1, l2, l3,l4]]`, what should I put in `Transpose[old, ]`?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, It's a question of permuting the levels.  For your second question `FindPermutation[{l1, l2, l3, l4}, {l2, l3, l1, l4}] // PermutationList[#, 4] &` will return what you need.  For the first, in `{l3,l1,l2}`, `l1` went to position `2`; so the permutation start with `{2,..}`; next `l2` went to position `3`, so the permutation becomes `{2, 3,...}`; finally, `l3` went to position `1`, so the argument to `Transpose` is/was `{2, 3, 1}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a math question, but in the spirit of being helpful:

I think if you run this code and look at the colors of each matrix you might understand better what transpose does.

```
    m = Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, .33 i, .33 j], Disk[]}], {i, 1, 3},
     {j,1,3}] // MatrixForm;
    mT = Transpose@Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, .33 i, .33 j], Disk[]}],
     {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm;
    Row[{m, mT}]
```

Transpose basically reflects elements across the diagonal.

Notice how the first column of the original matrix is the same as the first row of the transposed matrix.

Comment: I think the OP had in mind the syntax with the second argument of `Transpose`, which allows complex array reshuffles for arrays of higher dimensions, rather than the (trivial) single-arg `Transpose`.