# Factor out the scalar multiplier for the dot product of 2x2 matrices

Tags: matrix, dot

If yy and zz are 2x2 Hermitian matrices, is there a way that I can mark them (with a property?) as Hermitian so that Mathematica can assume that it can factor out and simplify scalar multipliers from a dot product expression? In this example, we have -1 * -1 as the multiplier:

```
ClearAll[a, yy, zz]
a = -(-yy.zz).zz
FullForm[a]
```

This gives:

```
-(-yy.zz).zz
Times[-1,Dot[Times[-1,Dot[yy,zz]],zz]]
```

Can it be made to simplify to just:

```
yy.zz.zz
```

Comment: Dave, just a gentle reminder that, if one of the answers provided below solve your problem, you might want to accept it by clicking on the gray check mark next to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To factor out numeric factors in any argument of `Dot`:

```
(2 yy.(3 zz)).(4 zz) //. Dot[a___, d_?NumericQ b_, c___] :> d Dot[a, b, c]
```

> `24 yy.zz.zz`

---

**Edit:** If you want this to happen automatically, you can add the rule as a new definition for `Dot`:

```
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[a___, d_?NumericQ b_, c___] := d Dot[a, b, c]
Protect[Dot];
```

Now the factoring happens by itself:

```
(2 yy.(3 zz)).(4 zz)
```

> `24 yy.zz.zz`

Comment: Thanks; this is a nice and straightforward replacement that will do the job. I must say, though, that I was hoping that Mathematica could just "figure it out".

Comment: @daveboden You can make it automatic, if you like -- see the edit.

Comment: Please, try your code for this string `J.Transpose[(-P)].x`

Comment: And for this: `J.Transpose[1].x`, `J.Transpose[-1].x` and `J.Transpose[-P].(-1)`

Comment: @dtn, I see you have asked your question under multiple answers but I think it is unclear to people exactly what you mean. In your first problem, do you want ```Transpose[1]``` to return the identity, such that ```J.Transpose[1].x``` reduces to ```J.x```? I think Mathematica can't do that because it doesn't know the dimensions of ```J``` and ```x``` so that it can't return identity matrix of proper dimensions. At least as far as I know Mathematica can't do that. Perhaps a Mathematica export can comment on this.

Answer (score 4):

Is the following sufficiently general?

```
t[e_] := e /. Dot[Times[z1_ /;!ArrayQ[z1], Dot[z2__]], z3__] :> z1 Dot[z2, z3]    
Simplify[a, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
(* yy.zz.zz *)
```

Comment: Please, try your code for this string `J.Transpose[(-P)].x`

Comment: @dtn, What are the three quantities in your expression?

Comment: `J`,`Transpose[-P]` and `x`

Answer (score 3):

Easier and more generally applicable is to use `TensorExpand`:

```
In[]: -(-yy.zz).zz//TensorExpand
Out[]: yy.zz.zz
```

Comment: Your code work for this string `J.Transpose[(-P)].x`, but how to return the standard notation for transpose?

Comment: Is your question that ```J.Transpose[(-P)].x//TensorExpand``` returns ```-J.Transpose[P, {2, 1}].x``` but you want ```J.Transpose[P].x```? Besides what it would mean mathematically a way to get this output is to use a replacement rule in the following way ```(J.Transpose[(-P)].x//TensorExpand)//Transpose[a_, {2, 1}] :> Transpose[a]```. For a better understanding of what the ```{2,1}``` means you can lookup the documentation of ```Transpose``` or have a look at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45972/understanding-transpose).