# Trouble simplifying using Replace

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, replacement, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression:

```
w.a.b.r+w.c.d.r
```

I want to get:

```
w.(a.b+c.d).r
```

So far I used ReplaceRepeated:

```
In= ReplaceRepeated[w.a.b.r+w.c.d.r,{
     Plus[Dot[FRONT__,AA__,BACK__],Dot[FRONT__,BB__,BACK__]]->Dot[FRONT,Plus[AA,BB],BACK]
}]
```

However this gives:

```
Out= w.(a+b+c+d).r
```

Looking into AA shows that it equals:

```
Sequence[a, b]
```

Obviously the Dot operator is not begin retained in AA and BB so instead of `a.b+c.d` I get `a+b+c+d`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `:>` in place of `->` and change `Plus[AA,BB]` to `Plus[Dot[AA], Dot[BB]]`. (You saw that `AA` is matching `Sequence[a, b]`, so you've got to wrap it in `Dot`; otherwise, `Plus[AA, BB]` is `Plus[a, b, c, d]`.)

Comment: @march Thanks! That works, but now there is an issue. If I have instead `w.g.a.b.r+w.g.c.d.r` I want to get `w.g.(a.b+c.d).r`, but instead I get `w.(g.a.b+g.c.d).r`. How do I make sure that FRONT is the longest matching expression and not just the first term?

Comment: This is a quick, untested kluge, but wrap one of the `FRONT__`'s in `Longest`. That will force the pattern matching to find the longest sequence that matches.

Comment: @march Your suggestions seem to work for both of the OP's problems. I think it would be great if you had time to convert your comments to an answer, maybe with a bit of commentary as well.

Comment: @MarcoB. Sure. As soon as he had the extra question, I figured it would be useful to write a full answer. I'l get to it when I can.

Comment: Both answers worked, thanks a lot! I'll accept it as an answer when you write it.

Comment: This is the second [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89183/factor-out-the-scalar-multiplier-for-the-dot-product-of-2x2-matrices) involving `Dot` that I have seen in the past few days, in which one would expect Simplify to simplify the expression, but it does not.

Comment: @bbgodfrey. The `Dot` help page says that `Dot` remains unevaluated if one or more of its arguments is something other than a `List` or `SparseArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, we modify the code as follows:

```
replacementRule = Plus[
  Dot[FRONT__, AA__, BACK__]
  , Dot[FRONT__, BB__, BACK__]
 ] :> Dot[FRONT, Plus[Dot[AA], Dot[BB]], BACK]}]
w.a.b.r + w.c.d.r /. replacementRule
```

First, we have changed `->` (`Rule`) to `:>` (`RuleDelayed`) so that when the expression is re-written, it will write it using the sub-expressions that *match* `FRONT`, `AA`, etc. instead of merely putting in the symbols `FRONT`, `AA`, etc.

Second, as the OP noted, `AA__` matches a `Sequence`; in this case `AA__` matches `Sequence[a, b]`. The re-write will not "remember" that `a` and `b` are `Dot`ted, so we have to add this in by hand by wrapping `AA` with `Dot`.

As to the question that the OP posed in the comments: the OP wants to also re-write more complicated expressions. For instance, write `w.g.a.b.r + w.g.c.d.r` as `w.g.(a.b + c.d).r`. With the code as above, we get

```
w.g.a.b.r + w.g.c.d.r /. replacementRule
(* w.(g.a.b + g.c.d).r *)
```

The reason is that by default, the pattern matching algorithm matches the longest expression starting from the *end* of the list. To see what I mean, note that

```
{a, b, c, d} /. {x__, y__} :> {f[x], g[y]}
```

results in

```
{f[a], g[b, c, d]}
```

The patterns `x__` and `y__` both stand for sequence of one or more expressions, but since the pattern matching tries to match the longest matching expressions starting from the end of the list, `y__` gets matched to `Sequence[b, c, d]`, leaving `x__` to match `a`.

In the OP's example, `BACK__` matches only `r` because it has to match *the same* sequence of expressions in both expressions that are added together. However, since `AA__` and `BB__` can be different, the pattern matching eats up as many expressions to the left of `r` as it can, and this includes the `g`, leaving `FRONT__` to match `w`.

To fix the problem, we force the pattern-matching to match `FRONT__` to the longest sequence of expressions by adding wrapping it in `Longest`. Since `FRONT__` is the same in both expressions that are added together, it will match the longest sub-expression that is the same. Thus, we modify `replacementRule` as

```
replacementRule = Plus[
  Dot[Longest[FRONT__], AA__, BACK__]
  , Dot[FRONT__, BB__, BACK__]
 ] :> Dot[FRONT, Plus[Dot[AA], Dot[BB]], BACK]}]
```

in which case

```
w.g.a.b.r + w.g.c.d.r /. replacementRule
```

yields

```
(* w.g.(a.b + c.d).r *)
```

Note that we don't need to modify the pattern as written to rewrite `w.g.a.b.f.r + w.g.c.d.f.r` as `w.g.(a.b + c.d).f.r` since, again, the pattern-matching matches the longest expression it can starting from the end of the list.

Comment: Very comprehensive, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with

```
w.a.b.r + w.c.d.r /. 
  Dot[FRONT_, AA__, BACK_] + Dot[FRONT_, BB__, BACK_] :> 
    Dot[FRONT, Dot[AA] + Dot[BB], BACK]
```

> ```
> w.(a.b + c.d).r
> ```

However, I like function argument destructuring, so I would probably write

```
f[Dot[w_, a__, r_] + Dot[w_, b__, r_]] := w.(Dot[a] + Dot[b]).r
f[w.a.b.r + w.c.d.r]
```

> w.(a.b + c.d).r

Comment: From now on, I *also* like function destructuring.

Comment: @march. Function argument destructuring is a very powerful, but IMO underused _Mathematica_ feature.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. This kind of construction hadn't occurred to me. There are all kinds of problems I've had in the past that would have been solved way more simply in this way. (So +1.)