# Factor constants out of multiple dot products

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, dot

I have expressions of the type

```
(-y A.A).(-y A.A).(A x).(A x) (* Example 1 *)

(-y A.A).(-y A.A).(A x) (* Example 2 *)
```

The number of parenthesis factors can vary, and the number of factors of A in each parenthesis can vary. However, each parenthesis has at least one factor of A.

I want to pull out the constants x and y from these expressions to obtain:

```
x^2 y^2 A.A.A.A.A.A (* Example 1 *)

x y^2 A.A.A.A.A (* Example 2 *)
```

What is the best way to go about this? I imagine it's going to be related to [that answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89183/factor-out-the-scalar-multiplier-for-the-dot-product-of-2x2-matrices), but somehow I can't make it work. It would be really nice if there was a very general way handling these quite usual operations.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that

```
TensorExpand[(-y A.A).(-y A.A).(A x).(A x),Assumptions->Element[{x,y},Reals]]
```

will do the job.