# Change the dimensions of an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array,`A`, with the dimensions

```
Dimensions[A] = {110, 105, 97} = {z,y,x}
```

These correspond to `z,y,x` values. I want the the `z` values to become `y` and the `x` to stay `x`. Which would result in the dimensions

```
Dimensions[A] = {105, 110, 97} = {y,z,x}
```

Comment: You want `Transpose`. If `Dimensions[A]` gives `{110,105,97}`, then `Dimensions[Transpose[A]]` gives `{105,110,97}`.

Comment: Using the second argument makes it clearer: `Dimensions@Transpose[RandomReal[1, {5, 4, 2}], {2, 1, 3}]`

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [(45972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45972/understanding-transpose)