# Why does 'Transpose[list]' work but 'Map[Transpose[#]&, list]' not when attempting to transpose a 2D-array list?

Tags: warning-messages, syntax, list-manipulation

I define this list:

```
list={{100,100},{200,200}}
```

Taking the transpose like this works as intended:

```
Transpose[list]
```

Taking the transpose like this yields an error message saying "Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {100,100} cannot be transposed.":

```
Map[Transpose[#]&, list]
```

Why aren't these two ways of taking the transpose equivalent? I've looked at the documentation on [Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), but I can't figure out why the latter doesn't work. It looks like it should simply take `list` and put it where the `#` is, yet it doesn't.

Comment: You can do `Map[Transpose, list, {0}]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45972/understanding-transpose

Comment: `Transpose[#]&` can be simplified as `Transpose`.

Comment: No, `Map[Transpose[#]&, list]` takes each _entry_ of the list, puts it where the `#` is and wraps the resulting sequence with `{ }`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Map` will iterate over the list and apply some function element-wise. In your case, `list` is a 2D-array, so `Map` will iterate over the the elements of `list`, which are `{100,100}` and `{200,200}`. These are the values that are then applied to `Transpose`, which will clearly fail.

To better illustrate this, you can use some undetermined function `f` to see what's going on:

```
Clear[f]
Map[f[#] &, list]
(* {f[{100, 100}], f[{200, 200}]} *)
```

Replacing `f` with `Transpose` would then give

```
{Transpose[{100, 100}], Transpose[{200, 200}]}
```

which results in an error.

---

**Edit:** As Chris mentioned in the comments, this behavior can be controlled by the level spec. By, default, `Map` will map at the "first" level, which in the case of a 2D array like here, means that the mapped elements are lists themselves. However, if you use

```
 Map[Transpose, list, {0}]
```

this forces `Map` to only map elements on the "zeroth" level, which means the whole expression. This would be equivalent to

```
 Transpose[list]
```

If you use level 2, `Map` would go over every element in the 2D array like this:

```
 Map[f, list, {2}]
 (* {{f[100], f[100]}, {f[200], f[200]}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

An explanation of the description:

> `Transpose[list]`
>   transposes the first two levels in `list`.

If `Transpose` is applied at level $n$, then levels $n+1$ and $n+2$ are transposed, if the expression has a suitable structure: The expression must have levels $n+1$ and $n+2$, and the levels must form a "rectangular array" structure (e.g., a list of equal-length lists).

`Transpose[list]` applies `Transpose` at level 0 and transposes levels 1 and 2.

`Transpose /@ list` (or `Map[Transpose[#]&, list]`) applies `Transpose` at level 1 and transposes levels 2 and 3.

The OP's `list` has only two levels, so the second code results in an error.

---

The `FullForm` of `list` has the following level structure:

```
(*          level        0 *)
List[    (* level      1 | *)
  List[  (* level    2 | | *)
    100,100       (* 2 | | *)
  ],              (*   1 | *)
  List[  (* level    2 | | *)
    200,200       (* 2 | | *)
  ]               (*   1 | *)
]                 (*     0 *)
```

Every expression has a level structure of some sort. It's not easy to see the rectangular-array structure in `FullForm`. It may be visualized like this:

```
List
  ↓
 List ⟶  100 ⟶  100
  ↓
 List ⟶  200 ⟶  200
```

`Transpose[list]` restructures the expression like this:

```
List ⟶  List ⟶ List
           ↓        ↓
          100      100
           ↓        ↓
          200      200
```