# How can I make a lists of pairs out of two lists of triples?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to use this expression for my computation:

```
FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0,
Transpose[Join[{ea, cm}]]]
```

My problem now is that `ea` and `cm` is not only one list each it is a set of lists. How can I make a list of pairs out of these two set of lists?

For example:

```
ea = {{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 9}} 
cm = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

and i want a list of pairs of these lists but again in one list each like these:

```
eacm = 
  {{{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}}}
```

My real lists are longer than those shown above. I have 720 numbers in each list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Transpose[{ea, cm}, {3, 1, 2}]

Flatten[{ea, cm}, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]
```

Comment: Ok but i will have the problem that i will have 10.000 lists i a row because i am doing a monte carlo simulation

Comment: sorry you couldn´t know but thank you very much for your solution

Comment: @user41673. I don't see how having two lists of 10000 triples invalidates this answer.

Comment: A very interesting explanation about `Transpose` second argument [here -> 16968](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16968)

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment on Hotoke's answer.

The OP seems to think `Transpose` isn't applicable when `ea` and `cm` are very long lists, say, of 10000 triples each. Perhaps the OP thinks it would be very slow is such a case. But actually it is very fast even for long lists, as I will demonstrate here.

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 10000, k = 12},
  Module[{m, mt, t},
    m = RandomInteger[42, {2, n, 3}];
    t = AbsoluteTiming[mt = Transpose[m, {3, 1, 2}]][[1]];
    {t, Column[{#, mt[[#]]} & /@ RandomSample[Range[n], k]]}]]
```

[image: result]

It still works well even if the sublists are longer. Here is example with 5-tuples.

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 10000, i = 5, k = 8},
  Module[{m, mt, t},
    m = RandomInteger[42, {2, n, i}];
    t = AbsoluteTiming[mt = Transpose[m, {3, 1, 2}]][[1]];
    {t, Column[{#, mt[[#]]} & /@ RandomSample[Range[n], k]]}]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: That's some hardcore localization you got going on there ;))

Comment: @E.Doroskevic. I like to live clean :-)

Answer (score 5):

Does it fit your needs?

```
MapThread[List, {ea, cm}, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
Transpose @ # & /@ Transpose[{ea, cm}]
```

*Note:* `ea` and `cm` same as in original post

Answer (score 2):

`Transpose` second argument is like magic/cryptic for me. Here is another option using `Map`:

```
Map[Transpose, Transpose@{ea, cm}, {-3}]
```