# How to riffle matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have four matrices

```
m = {{M11, M12, M13}, {M21, M22, M23}, {M31, M32, M33}};
n = {{N11, N12, N13}, {N21, N22, N23}, {N31, N32, N33}};
p = {{P11, P12, P13}, {P21, P22, P23}, {P31, P32, P33}};
q = {{Q11, Q12, Q13}, {Q21, Q22, Q23}, {Q31, Q32, Q33}};
```

and i want to construct the following

```
ArrayFlatten[Table[{{m[[k1, k2]], n[[k1, k2]]}, {p[[k1, k2]], q[[k1, k2]]}}, {k1,1, 3}, {k2, 1, 3}]]

 {{M11, N11, M12, N12, M13, N13},
  {P11, Q11, P12, Q12, P13, Q13},
  {M21, N21, M22, N22, M23, N23},
  {P21, Q21, P22, Q22, P23, Q23},
  {M31, N31, M32, N32, M33, N33},
  {P31, Q31, P32, Q32, P33, Q33}}
```

There is a more elegant and rapid way to this thing?

Comment: `ArrayFlatten@Transpose[{{m, n}, {p, q}}, {3, 4, 1, 2}]`

Comment: Of course, because of the relationship between [`Flatten[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119) and [`Transpose[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16968), Carl's and Simon's snippets are equivalent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use `Flatten`:

```
m = {{M11, M12, M13}, {M21, M22, M23}, {M31, M32, M33}};
n = {{N11, N12, N13}, {N21, N22, N23}, {N31, N32, N33}};
p = {{P11, P12, P13}, {P21, P22, P23}, {P31, P32, P33}};
q = {{Q11, Q12, Q13}, {Q21, Q22, Q23}, {Q31, Q32, Q33}};

Flatten[{{m, n}, {p, q}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}}] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{pmatrix}
>  \text{M11} & \text{N11} & \text{M12} & \text{N12} &
>    \text{M13} & \text{N13} \\
>  \text{P11} & \text{Q11} & \text{P12} & \text{Q12} &
>    \text{P13} & \text{Q13} \\
>  \text{M21} & \text{N21} & \text{M22} & \text{N22} &
>    \text{M23} & \text{N23} \\
>  \text{P21} & \text{Q21} & \text{P22} & \text{Q22} &
>    \text{P23} & \text{Q23} \\
>  \text{M31} & \text{N31} & \text{M32} & \text{N32} &
>    \text{M33} & \text{N33} \\
>  \text{P31} & \text{Q31} & \text{P32} & \text{Q32} &
>    \text{P33} & \text{Q33} \\
> \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know this use the Flatten function!! Thanks

Comment: @Kowalski [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/5467) are some explanations about the generalized form of `Flatten`, though personally, I have still difficulties to find the right index ordering.

Comment: @Carl can you also explain how you determine the indices for `Flatten`?

Comment: I just experiment.

Answer (score 3):

```
♮ = ## & @@@ (#) &@(## & @@@ (#) & /@ (#) & /@ {##}) &;
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
♮[{m, n}, {p, q}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]