# Ways to compute inner products of tensors

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, summation

One way to evaluate the following sums is combining Table and Sum:

$u_{abcd} = \sum_{e=1}^3 v_{aeb}w_{ced}$

$q_{ab} = \sum_{d,e=1}^3 v_{d e a}w_{deb}$

It will look like

```
v = Table[Times[i, j, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]
w = Table[Times[i+2, j-1, k+1], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]

u = Table[Sum[v[[a, e, b]] w[[c, e, d]], {e, 3}], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}, {d,  3}]
q = Table[Sum[v[[d, e, a]] w[[d, e, b]], {d, 3}, {e, 3}], {a, 3}, {b, 3}]
```

Is there a more  elegant way to evaluate sums like these?

Comment: Just replacing the sum with `Dot` as in `u2 = Outer[Dot[v[[#1, All, #2]], w[[#3, All, #4]]] &, Range[3], 
  Range[3], Range[3], Range[3]]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'm curious why you didn't post that as an answer.  I took the liberty of posting it for you, but I encourage you to post such things yourself in the future.  If you wish to post it now, I'll be glad to delete mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's not gonna be more helpful in an answer and it's quicker to add a comment. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @b.gatessucks actually, it is: comments cannot be Accepted and voting is limited.  It takes hardly a moment longer to make an answer than a comment, and you should get the credit for your own answers/ideas.  Nevertheless, it's your prerogative.

Comment: From the [tutorial on tensors](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Tensors.html): "You can think of Inner as performing a "contraction" of the last index of one tensor with the first index of another. If you want to perform contractions across other pairs of indices, you can do so by first transposing the appropriate indices into the first or last position, then applying Inner, and then transposing the result back." For multiple contractions, as in the second example, transpose all involved indexes to the end, Flatten them into a single index, and then perform a contraction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If we transpose the indices of $v$ and $w$ so that $v'_{abe} = v_{aeb}$ and $w'_{ecd} = w_{ced}$, then we can compute $u = v' \cdot w'$:

```
u === Transpose[v, {1, 3, 2}] . Transpose[w, {2, 1, 3}]
(* True *)
```

We can use a similar trick to compute $q$ if we reorder $v_{dea} \to v''_{ade}$, except that this time the $d$ and $e$ indices in $v_{ade}''$ and $w_{deb}$ must treated as if they comprised a single index to be contracted.  `Flatten` can do this for us:

```
q === Flatten[v, {{3}, {1, 2}}] . Flatten[w, {{1, 2}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

For details about the `Flatten` syntax used here, see [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142).

Comment: Much better.  I was trying to figure this out myself earlier but failed. Big +1.

Comment: For anyone coming here in more modern times (i.e. after the advent of `TensorContract`, `TensorProduct`, and crucially `Inactive`) there is a later answer by Bren that reformulates [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77566/38205) by Jose Martin-Garcia and which is much more convenient and much faster for large tensors.

Answer (score 19):

In *Mathematica* version 9, you can do these kinds of things much more naturally. Here are the two quantities that you wanted:

```
u = TensorContract[TensorProduct[v, w], {2, 5}];

q = TensorContract[TensorProduct[v, w], {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}];
```

The contraction is performed on the tensor product in which the first three indices belong to the factor `v` and the last three indices label `w`. Therefore, the indices corresponding to $e$ in your sum for `u` are in slots `{2, 5}`, and the two summations for `q` run over slots `{1, 4}` (for the variable $d$) and `{2,5}` (as in `v`).

Comment: No love for this answer?  If it works it's nice.  (I can't test it.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Trust me, it works, it's the best. I consider this to be one of the most important news in `ver.9`, much more interesting than `auto-completion` tosh.

Comment: @Artes Thanks - and I still haven't gotten used to autocompletion; when it appears and I want to just navigate away by down-arrow, it annoyingly snags the cursor... I guess we have to take the good with the bad.

Comment: @Jens Since I've been  getting used to autocompletion for 2 months, it seems quite natural and sometimes I lack it when using `ver.8`. Nevertheless I find it's a toy unlike the new tensor capabilites which are definitely still underestimated.

Comment: @Artes I think I'd like it better if autocomplete choices only appeared *after* pressing a certain special key (like Tab), not immediately while in the middle of a word. I find that intrusive.

Comment: @Jens Doesn't this waste memory in a huge way because the calculation stores the tensor product as an intermediate value? Or does TensorProduct have a special UpValue or something...

Comment: @IanHincks Yes, it's wasteful if the tensors are large, but on the other hand it's very easy on the eyes. The question asked for elegance, and that's of course in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer though. It's much more elegant.

Answer (score 11):

Since the question "[Efficient tensor product followed by contraction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77511/efficient-tensor-product-followed-by-contraction)" asking for an efficient solution to this problem has been marked as a duplicate, I find it appropriate to add here an encapsulated version of the answer to that question by [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg). Note that this works efficiently for the contraction of any number of index pairs. The notation follows *Mathematica*'s [TensorContract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract.html?q=TensorContract).

> TensorMultiply[ A, B, {{$a_1$,$b_1$},{$a_2$,$b_2$},...} ]

$\hspace{7.5mm}$yields the tensor product of tensors A and B in the pairs  {$a_i$,$b_i$} of slots.

```
TensorMultiply[A_, B_, pairs_] := 
  Activate@TensorContract[
    Inactive[TensorProduct][A, B], (# + {0, TensorRank[A]}) & /@ pairs];
```

Comment: I must have overlooked this earlier - it works very well (+1).

Comment: This is both quite clever and very efficient! (It makes sense that this works as well as it does as it was proposed by Jose Martin-Garcia). For high dimensional tensors this vastly outperforms the `Transpose` approach. It is also vastly more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Incorporating b.gatessucks's recommendation:

```
u === Outer[v[[#1, All, #2]].w[[#3, All, #4]] &, ##] & @@ Range@{3, 3, 3, 3}
```

> True

Comment: How would you calculate q with Outer[] and Dot[]?

Answer (score 4):

## Edit

This is the fastest solution:

```
Do[TensorContract[TensorProduct[v, w], {2, 5}], {10000}] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
Do[TensorMultiply[v, w, {{2, 2}}], {10000}] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
Do[Activate@TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][v, w], {2, 5}], {10000}] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
Do[DotAt[v, w, 2, 2], {10000}] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
```

```
{5.36688, {5.36012, Null}}
{0.753744, {0.752581, Null}}
{0.57401, {0.573111, Null}}
{0.143519, {0.143405, Null}}
```

## Original answer

As used in a [recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91251/6478) recent answer, one can easily define a function which contracts two tensors:

```
DotAt[T_?TensorQ, U_?TensorQ, m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
    With[{dimT = Length@Dimensions@T, dimU = Length@Dimensions@U},
        Dot[Transpose[T, Insert[Range[dimT - 1], dimT, m]], 
            Transpose[U, Insert[Range[2, dimU], 1, n]]]]
```

`DotAt` contracts the index `m` of `T` with the index `n` of `U`.

This way, `u = TensorContract[TensorProduct[v, w], {2, 5}];` would become `u = DotAt[v, w, 2, 2]`. This just shows that `Dot` and `Transpose` can be combined to perform all the operations and that it is actually quite easy to implement a form of `TensorContract` with the syntax that one prefers.