# Summing tensors in mathematica

Tags: sparse-arrays, tensors, summation

How do I perform the following summation in mathematica?
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{m=1}^5 e_{ijklm}A^{mn}
\end{equation}
I have the $e_{ijklm}$ tensor of rank 5 in 5 dimension as a array and $A^{mn}$ as a 5x5 matrix.

Answer (score 7):

Since the sum goes over the last index of $e$ and the first index of $A$, it is directly done by using `Dot`:

```
dim = 5;

e = Array[\[ScriptE], Table[dim, {dim}]];

a = Array[\[ScriptA], Table[dim, {2}]];

c = e.a;
```

Here I defined the arrays with the appropriate dimensions but suppressed the output because it's too long for five dimensions.

Another interesting alternative for more general sums is what I mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17798/245), but it requires version 9:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[e, a], {dim, dim+1}] == c
```

> `True`

Here the `{dim, dim+1}` are just the last index of the first factor and the first index of the second factor. The latter can be generalized to sums over say `k` etc.