# Change of basis for a rank 3 Cartesian tensor

Tags: tensors

I have a Cartesian tensor $\chi_{ijk}$ and I want to express the elements in terms of a new basis to get $\chi_{ijk}^\prime$.  The transformation is represented using $a_{ij}$.  The tensor transforms as $\chi_{ijk}^\prime = a_{il}a_{jm}a_{kn}\chi_{lmn}$.  Is there a way to implement this change of basis in *Mathematica*? I am new to tensors in general as well as their representation in *Mathematica* so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
X = Array[x, {3, 3, 3}];
A = Array[a, {3, 3}];

TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, A, A, X], {{2, 7}, {4, 8}, {6, 9}}]
```

Look at your expression A[i,l] A[j,m] A[k,n] X[l,m,n], count positions of repeated indices and you will see that each contraction pair corresponds to a repeated index.

However, there is a problem there: TensorProduct constructs a big intermediate array, and we don't need it. If your arrays have large dimensions, this intermediate array can be enormous. It can be avoided as follows:

```
Activate[TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][A, A, A, X], {{2, 7}, {4, 8}, {6, 9}}]]
```

The idea is that Inactive prevents the construction of the intermediate array, but TensorContract knows what to do. It returns another Inactive[TensorProduct][...] expression, so we need to undo that with the final Activate.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was looking at using higher order tensors and this will help me save some computation time.

Answer (score 1):

I used the ideas from this post, [Ways to compute inner products of tensors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/ways-to-compute-inner-products-of-tensors), to help in obtaining a solution.  The main idea here is to transpose the tensor so that the indices in the original expression for $\chi^{\prime}_{ijk}$ are near each other then use the inner product.  In *Mathematica*, use the transpose function to exchange the indices.  The proper sequence in *Mathematica* code for changing the basis of a rank three tensor is:

```
T = Table[Subscript[t, i, j, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}];
R = Table[Subscript[r, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
Tprime = Transpose[
R.Transpose[(R.Transpose[(R.Transpose[T, {3, 2, 1}]), {2, 1, 
     3}]), {3, 2, 1}], {1, 3, 2}];
```

R represents the rotation matrix, T represents the $3^{rd}$ rank tensor, and Tprime is the tensor in the new basis.