# Efficient tensor product followed by contraction

Tags: tensors

Say I want to efficiently evaluate $\sum_{kl}A_{ikjl}B_{kl}$ where $A$, $B$ are numerical tensors. This has been discussed [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/ways-to-compute-inner-products-of-tensors) but with no focus on efficiency. A straightforward way as mentioned there would be

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}]
```

but this is extremely inefficient both in terms of memory and time.

I came up with

```
TensorProdContract = 
  Function[{A, B, dims}, 
   Transpose[#, RotateRight@Range@ArrayDepth[#]] &@
     Flatten[A, List@Transpose[dims][[1, All]]].Flatten[B, 
     List@Transpose[dims][[2, All]]]];
```

which flattens the contracted dimensions and rearranges the arrays so that the fast `Dot` function can be used. It would be called like

```
TensorProdContract[A, B, {{2, 1}, {4, 2}}]
```

But even so, for all dimensions sized at 50, this takes 0.15 seconds on my computer, whereas the `tprod` library for Matlab (basically compiled code) can do the same thing in 10 times shorter time (called as `tprod(A, [1 -1 2 -2], B, [-1 -2])`). For size 100, it's 3.5 seconds vs. 0.15 seconds. Given that this should work for arrays of general rank, the `Compile` approach cannot be really used as far as I know.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From profiling the code, most time (basically all the difference between Mathematica and Matlab) is spent on the `Flatten`/`Transpose` of the 4-D array.

Comment: My method is equivalent to what @WReach came up with in there. It suffers in terms of speed from having to do all the list manipulation though. The answer by @jose below deals with the inefficiency of the `TensorContract`/`TensorProduct` approach.

Comment: [I've mentioned now the very related question which does not discuss efficiency at all though. The answer below by @jose is the best for both my and the original question. What should happen now?]

Comment: Have you tried WReach's `Transpose` method?  It appears to be quite fast.  Please include code to generate sample data and show that the available methods are still slow.

Answer (score 5):

Take two arrays like you describe:

```
n = 100;
A = RandomReal[1, {n, n, n, n}];
B = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
```

With your solution

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Dimensions[result1 = TensorProdContract[A, B, {{2, 1}, {4, 2}}]]]
```

> ```
> {2.22103, {100, 100}}
> ```

To avoid the inefficiency you refer to above, inactivate the tensor product and activate back at the end:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Dimensions[
    result2 = 
      Activate @ TensorContract[
        Inactive[TensorProduct][A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}]]]
```

> ```
> {1.2759, {100, 100}}
> ```

```
result1 === result2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Wow, that's some use of `Inactivate`. Could you elaborate on how exactly does this work? I see that `TensorProduct` is left with literally nothing to do in this case. Does `TensorContract` basically crunch through the arguments of `TensorProduct`, figures out the result symbolically and replaces the arguments? I also see that if I replace `TensorProduct` with `Inactive[someHead]`, this does not happen, does it mean that this behaviour is explicitly built into `TensorContract` to work with `TensorProduct`? It's a shame this is not documented if that's the case.

Comment: I see this is still much slower than `Dot` for cases when `Dot` can be used. Do you see any way to combine my solution with `Inactivate` to harness the speed of `Dot` without doing all the list manipulation? Or would that be impossible because `Dot` is using some native-code library which directly crunches the blocks of reals as they are in the memory?