# Performance improvements by using Activate and Inactivate

Tags: performance-tuning, tensors

In a [question about improving performance of a `TensorContract` of a `TensorProduct`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77511/34455), user jose [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77566/34455) replacing

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}]
```

with

```
Activate @ TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}]
```

where e.g. for a minimal example:

```
n = 10;
A = RandomReal[1, {n, n, n, n}];
B = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
```

Using this example, the version with `Inactivate`/`Activate` is about 30 times faster (according to `RepeatedTiming`) and uses about 200 times less memory (according to `MaxMemoryUsed`).

Obviously Mathematica uses some special algorithm to contract the two tensors without actually constructing the whole tensor product.

Now my questions is:

When does using `Activate` and `Inactivate` improve performance as drastically as above? 
How could I've known that using `Activate` and `Inactivate` lets Mathematica use more powerful tools?
I'm looking for examples, heuristics or hidden Documentation.

Comment: Everywhere where deeper evaluations are heavy but will not affect the result. `Activate@Length@{Inactive[Pause][5]}`

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, that seems a good heuristic although it fails for e.g. `Activate@Part[Inactive[RandomReal][{0,1},10^9],1;;10]` where I would've expected only the first 10 elements to be generated.

Comment: Maybe I should improve the wording but `Part[Inactive[RandomReal][{0, 1}, 10^9], 1 ;; 10]` doesn't make sense while `Length@{Inactive[Pause][5]}` does.

Comment: @kuba, my assumption was that `Part[Inactive[RandomReal[{0,1},10^9],1;;10]` create the "promise of a list" and then just take the first 10 elements and actually evaluate them, similar to lazy behaviour in e.g. haskell.
If you have a moment I would appreciate a short answer with a few examples if you can think of any.

Comment: I see, I'm afraid that concept doesn't exist in WL but something similar happens for Datasets querying: [85363](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85363/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Strictly speaking, you are right, but there exists some undocumented functionality for lazy operations, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85336/81). Can't say whether or to what extent that would remain in future versions, though.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, wasn't aware of that.