# The fastest way of raising indices of high rank tensor

Tags: performance-tuning, summation, tensors

I have some high dimensional high rank tensors, let's say $$F_{ijkl}$$ and I need to find $$F^{abcd}=g^{ai}g^{bj}g^{ck}g^{dl}F_{ijkl}.$$ 
Here $g^{ij}$ is the contravariant metric.

Simple summation in Mathematica takes way to much time

```
Do[Fup[[a,b,c,d]]=Sum[F[[j,j,k,l]]g[[a,i]]g[[b,j]]g[[c,k]]g[[d,l]],{i,1,dim},{j,1,dim},{k,1,dim},{l,1,dim}],{a,1,dim},{b,1,dim},{c,1,dim},{d,1,dim}]
```

But I can sum over first and last index using matrix multiplication, so first I calculate $F^a{}_{ij}{}^d$ and the do summation over last two indices:

```
Fuddu=g.F.g; Do[F^{abcd}=Sum[Fuddu[[a,j,k,d]]g[[b,j]]g[[c,k]],{j,1,dim},{k,1,dim}],{a,1,dim},{b,1,dim},{c,1,dim},{d,1,dim}]
```

This way is much faster but still takes a lot of time, I need smth even faster, any ideas guys?

Edit: I cannot give you my info, but you can choose some big `dim` like 10, fill square matrix `g` of dimension `dim` and rank-4 tensor `F` of dimension `dim` with some random functions/numbers:

```
dim=10;g=RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dim, dim}];F=RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dim, dim,dim,dim}];
```

Comment: I ran your code as is, but I get a bunch of errors.  `dim` is not specified and `Fup`, `g` is not initialized as an array, *etc*.  Please add the additional information.

Comment: I think the built-in function `TensorContract` will be helpful to you.

Comment: It is only in Mathematica 10, and it is only symbolic, no?

Comment: @g3n1uss Notice there is a type in the first computation: it should be `...Sum[F[[i,j,k,l]]...`

Answer (score 6):

My keyboard is broken.  So here is fast answer (on Mathematica 9); more later...

Here is your input:

```
dim = 3; g = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dim, dim}];
F = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dim, dim, dim, dim}];
```

Now multiply four `g`'s and the `F`.  Use `TensorProduct[g, g, g, g, F]` (don't run this yet--it's slow) to generate the rank 12 tensor (unrepeated indices).

Now contract the 2nd and 9th indices, 4th and 10th indices, 6th and 11th indices, and also the 8th and 12th indices:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[g, g, g, g, F], {{2, 9}, {4, 10}, {6, 11}, {8, 12}}]
```

This is fastest I can get (0.3 sec on my machine).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do not have TensorContract (Mathematica 8).

Comment: aw :( buy upgrade

Comment: When using TensorContract in a situation like this, it is important to inactivate the TensorProduct to avoid a very large intermediate expression. The timing of Activate[TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][g, g, g, g, F], {{2, 9}, {4, 10}, {6, 11}, {8, 12}}]] is about 10^4 times faster than that without Activate/Inactive for dim=5. And the gain is even larger in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

## Edit

My solution is faster than the accepted one, even with the `Activate`/`Inactive` trick suggested in the comments.

## Original answer

You can define your tensor contraction routine using the builtins `Dot` and `Transpose`. Here is an example:

```
DotAt[T_?TensorQ, U_?TensorQ, m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
    With[{dimT = ArrayDepth@T, dimU = ArrayDepth@U},
       Dot[Transpose[T, Insert[Range[dimT - 1], dimT, m]], 
           Transpose[U, Insert[Range[2, dimU], 1, n]]]]
```

`DotAt[T, U, m, n]` contracts the $m$-th index of $T$ with the $n$-th index of $U$. With this definition you have for example that `Dot[T, U]` is equivalent to `DotAt[T, U, Length@Dimensions@T, 1]`.

From this, you can go on and define the equivalent of `TensorContract`, with an easier syntax for multiple contractions, but I'm leaving that to you  :)

Your problem can now be solved by

```
myFup = DotAt[g, DotAt[g, DotAt[g, DotAt[g, F, 2, 4], 2, 4], 2, 4], 2, 4];
```