# TensorReduce and Dot

Tags: tensors, products, dot

I'm manipulating abstract tensors with Mathematica. I have a question. With the assumptions

```
$Assumptions = (R | r) ∈ Arrays[{4}];
```

I can do two operations: `R.r` and `TensorContract[R \[TensorProduct] r, {{1, 2}}]` which are the same obviously. The problem is that doing

```
 R.r - TensorContract[R \[TensorProduct] r, {{1, 2}}]
```

I cannot get `0` as expected. I try to apply `TensorReduce`, `TensorExpand`, `FullSimplify` and their combination without any result. What can I do?

Comment: Mathematica's tensor abilities are still rather kludgy, and not as powerful as some its more well-developed capabilities.  There may be a way to do this with a user-defined rule, and hopefully someone will provide an answer to that effect.  In the meantime, I would suggest using one form or the other (not both) throughout your code to perform this operation.

Comment: Do you know if some effort is being made to develop these abilities (as well as indices manipulation) or Mathematica staff is not interested in this branch of developing?

Comment: related: [Ways to compute inner products of tensors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17758/245), but this is different because it's about purely symbolic tensors.

Answer (score 4):

You could use my `TensorSimplify` package to do this. Install the paclet with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Once installed, you can load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

The basic issue is that [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) does not handle a mixture of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) and [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) objects very well. So, if one converts everything to the same types of objects ([`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) or [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract)), then [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) will be able to make headway. The `TensorSimplify` package includes two functions to help with this: `ToTensor` and `FromTensor`. Let's see these in action:

```
$Assumptions = (R | r) \[Element] Arrays[{4}];
expr = R.r-TensorContract[TensorProduct[R, r], {{1, 2}}];

ToTensor[expr]
FromTensor[expr]
```

> 0
>
> 0

It turns out that [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) is not even needed for this example. One could also use `TensorSimplify`:

```
TensorSimplify[expr]
```

> 0