# Translating MATLAB's cell2mat into Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, matlab

How I can define a function in *Mathematica* such that it acts same as the `cell2mat` command in MATLAB?

Example (in MATLAB):

```java
c = {[1],    [2, 3, 4];
     [5; 9], [6, 7, 8; 10, 11, 12]};
m = cell2mat(c)

%/* Output:
% m = 1     2     3     4
%     5     6     7     8
%     9     10    11    12
```

Comment: You've been around this site for a year now. You voted only once, posted 5 questions, never accepted an answer and never answered a question. Is the site really useful for you?

Comment: Your example is directly taken from the Matlab documentation and is therefore not valid Mathematica code. What Mathematica code have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Yet couldn't we legitimize this question? Is the example in Mathematica `{{{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{{5}, {9}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}}}}`? How does one turn this into normal matrix?

Comment: I see no good reason for all these down and close votes. The question is reasonable clear and answerable.

Comment: @BoLe I'm going to upvote your answer, but I think the question doesn't make any sense without context. Why should one drop down here a piece of syntactical sugar from any other language and ask for a "translation"?

Comment: @Matariki: yes, I thought maybe using Matlab original form may help the reader to better understand what I want to do. As a matter of fact my knowledge about Matlab is zero since I have only been using Mathematica. But recently I have started reading a book with all examples written in Matlab, so I have really hard time to understand those codes.

Comment: @BoLe: that is what exactly exactly made me think for a long time to figure it out, but I could not write an appropriate code! On paper, you can write the lists as 1x1   3x1                
                                           1x2   3x2
so, after merging you will have 4x3 matrix.

Comment: I think this would be a fine question if a description of what the Matlab code were intended to do had been included..

Comment: K-1,  @belisarius wasn't talking about the frequency of your visits to this site (he cannot see that), but rather that you don't seem to be participating in any way other than asking questions. We don't expect anyone to spend all their time here, but certain small actions, such as simply accepting the answer that helped you or at the _very least_, upvoting a useful answer to your own question is a good way of showing appreciation. It's just about being a good citizen of the site. You can still choose to not do them, but people might lose incentive to answer your questions in future...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries well `{[1], [2, 3, 4];[5; 9], [6, 7, 8; 10, 11, 12]}` isn't a valid Mathematica expression. The current answer basically takes an arbitrary (as far as I can tell) interpretation of the question and answers that; that's OK and I upvoted it, but it still doesn't make the question as it is clear. Perhaps the OP could modify the question  so that the current answer is actually an answer to it, since they've indicated that this is what they want.

Comment: @acl I don't think the OP intended that as Mathematica syntax (in fact, it is taken straight from [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)). It is Matlab syntax and he used is as an example of how he wanted the Mathematica version to work.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, that's my point, it is not mma syntax and not intended to. It puts the onus on the answerer.

Comment: K-1, rather than getting upset because people have down-voted the question, you could instead work to make it more clear.  Many people many not be familiar with MATLAB syntax and I think this question would have been much better received if you had given a generic "pseudo-code" example and *described* the operation.  Also, at the moment you are only -3 points as the up-votes count more than the down-votes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I do not think 'down-voted'  is always a good thing for the new forum-users, they may lose the motivation to ask any questions. Or not?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you have a concern I encourage you to post on https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ where it can be addressed by the community.  If you are only asking my personal opinion, I think "dog-piling" an inexperienced member does no good and could drive someone away, but at the same time they do need a signal that a question is poorly written, or they may have what I think is an even worse experience, that of seemingly being ignored.

Answer (score 12):

If you make all the component parts matrices, you can use `ArrayFlatten`

```
c = {{{{1}}, {{2, 3, 4}}}, {{{5}, {9}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}}}};
c // MatrixForm
ArrayFlatten[c] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree, this is the most natural way to do so. I was about to add this to my answer before I saw yours :) I hesitated at first, because the OP said BoLe's example is what they had in mind (but they probably didn't have a clue anyway, so it's better to show them the right way). My guess is that they got dinged badly in the votes because the lack of a clear example leads to different interpretations of what the original list should look like

Comment: @rm-rf, I hesitated too, but figured that without an example it was my choice how to define the *Mathematica* "equivalent" of `[2,3,4]`.

Comment: Yeah, I hope the OP chooses this. This is certainly the smarter way to do it.

Comment: @Simon Woods: I guess I would prefer this method as it suggests a general solution so for different matrices I don't need to check the dimensions all the time.

Answer (score 8):

There are already good explanations about how the restructuring of the nested arrays given as input to `cell2mat` can be done in Mathematica. I couldn't resist to mention the following, though:

The main purpose of the matlab function `cell2mat` is to convert from so called cell arrays to "normal" matlab matrices, where cell arrays correspond roughly to "normal" arrays (`List`) in Mathematica and normal matlab matrices correspond roughly to what Mathematica calls "packed arrays". The corresponding function in Mathematica would be `` Developer`ToPackedArray ``. Normal matlab matrices can -- just as Mathematica packed arrays -- only contain elements of exactly one data type and can only be rectangular. Thus the restructuring that `cell2mat` does in the OPs example more or less is just a side effect so that the conversion to a matrix will be possible at all. Unlike in Mathematica the use of cell arrays and matrices in matlab isn't interchangable, so it is often necessary to explicitly convert between the two, while in Mathematica the use of `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` is usually only used for performance optimizations. So one will see `cell2mat` and `num2cell` much more often in matlab code than `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` in Mathematica code just for that reason.

That said, one should be aware that `cell2mat` might indeed often be used for just such restructuring purposes in matlab code as it is a very convenient method to achieve that. It will only work if all elements are of the same type, though. This is the second reason why one probably sees `cell2mat` more often than `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` in Mathematica, which doesn't do any such restructuring.

Comment: So far, the best answer was your explanation about what cell2mat really does! Using your comment I finally concluded that maybe a Flatten command works out in my code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

```
 c = {{{1}, {2, 3, 4}},
   {{{5}, {9}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}}}};
```

This works for this example, perhaps you can tweak it to your needs.

```
Switch[Depth[#], 3, Join @@ #, 
   4, Sequence @@ Join @@@ Transpose[#]] & /@ c
```

Comment: You probably meant `... &/@c`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the powerful second argument of `Flatten` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5) by Leonid for an explanation) to do most of the work and finally partition it to the correct size. I'll use BoLe's example too:

```
c = {{{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{{5}, {9}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}}}};

With[{m = Flatten[c, {{1}, {3, 2}}]},
    Flatten@m ~Partition~ Length@Flatten@First@m
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the examples in BoLe's and Simon's answers:

```
c = {{{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{{5}, {9}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}}}};

ArrayFlatten @ Replace[c, x_?VectorQ :> {x}, {2}]
```

$
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}
$