# How to build a matrix from a set of vectors and other matrices using ArrayFlatten

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, concatenation

I want to build a 6 by 3 matrix, from the following: one vector is 3 by 1, then a matrix, which is 3 by 2. These will go to the top 3 rows. Now the bottom 3 rows, I'll have 3 vectors each is 3 by 1. Like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is easy to do this, when all the objects are the same. Say we have 6 vectors, each is 3 by 1. Like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But because I have a 3 by 2 matrix in there, `ArrayFlatten` is not happy for some reason.

I'll show the case with the 6 vectors first.

```
v1 = {1, 2, 3}; v2 = {4, 5, 6}; v3 = {7, 8, 9}; v4 = {10, 11, 12};
v5 = {13, 14, 15};  v6 = {16, 17, 18};
m = ArrayFlatten[{
    {Transpose@{v1}, Transpose@{v2}, Transpose@{v3}},
    {Transpose@{v4}, Transpose@{v5}, Transpose@{v6}}
    }
   ];
MatrixForm[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, in place of `v2` and `v3` above, I want to put a matrix, of same size as both, which is 3 by 2. Hence:

```
v1 = {1, 2, 3}; vNew = {{4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}};
v4 = {10, 11, 12}; v5 = {13, 14, 15};  v6 = {16, 17, 18};
```

Where `vNew` now takes place of `v2` and `v3`. But when I write

```
m = ArrayFlatten[{
    {Transpose@{v1}, vNew},
    {Transpose@{v4}, Transpose@{v5}, Transpose@{v6}}
    }
   ];
```

It does not work. I tried

```
m = ArrayFlatten[{
    {Join[Transpose@{v1}, vNew, 2]},
    {Transpose@{v4}, Transpose@{v5}, Transpose@{v6}}
    }
   ];
```

And few others things. It only works when I have each element of same shape. So this works

```
m = ArrayFlatten[{
    {Transpose@{v1}, Transpose@{vNew[[All, 1]]}, Transpose@{vNew[[All, 2]]}},
    {Transpose@{v4}, Transpose@{v5}, Transpose@{v6}}}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What should the correct syntax be?

PS: In [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), this is easy:

```
v1=[1,2,3]'; vNew=[4,5;6,7;8,9];v3=[10,11,12]'; v4=[13,14,15]';v5=[16,17,18]';
m=[v1 vNew;v3 v4 v5]

m =
     1     4     5
     2     6     7
     3     8     9
    10    13    16
    11    14    17
    12    15    18
```

I am using version 10.0.2.0

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22298/5478)

Comment: @Nasser, thank you for this question. I always have to deal with this issue. In many cases, I have v1 = {a, b, c};
v2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
v3 = {{10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60}, {70, 80, 90}}; V4v5v6 = {{1, 2, 3, 
   4, 5, 6}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}}; I want to make V = {{a, 1, 2, 10, 20, 30}, {b, 3, 4, 40, 50, 60}, {c, 5, 6, 70, 80, 
   90}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}}; I don't know why Mma is not user friendly in this case. If somebody could suggest more general function for this kind of job, I  would also be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: @ramesh `{
  {v1, v2, v3},
  {V4v5v6}
  } // myArrayFlatten`

Comment: @Kuba, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR;

```
myArrayFlatten = Flatten /@ Flatten[#, {{1, 3}}] &
```

`{x,y,z}` or `{{x},{y},{z}}` is considered column vector.

Usage example:

```
v1 = {1, 2, 3}; vNew = {{4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}};
v4 = {10, 11, 12}; v5 = {13, 14, 15}; v6 = List /@ {16, 17, 18};

{
 {v1, vNew, v1},
 {v4, v5, v6, v1},
 {vNew, vNew}
} // myArrayFlatten // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

### `Flatten` approach:

The fact that it is not working is due to:

> In `ArrayFlatten[{{m11, m12, ...},{m21, m22, ...},...}]` all the matrices m_ij in the same row must have the same first dimension, and matrices m_ij in the same column must have the same second dimension.

and

> `ArrayFlatten[a]` is normally equivalent to `Flatten[a,{{1,3},{2,4}}]`

is not our "normal(ly)" case! Beacuse it works when stated expicitly:

```
blocks = {{v1, vNew}, {v4, v5, v6}} // Replace[#, x_?VectorQ :> Transpose@List@x, {2}] &;

blocks // Flatten[#, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] &
blocks // ArrayFlatten
```

> ```
> {{1,4,5},{2,6,7},{3,8,9},{10,13,16},{11,14,17},{12,15,18}}
>
> ArrayFlatten[{{{{1},{2},{3}},{{4,5},{6,7},{8,9}}},{{{10},{11},{12}},{{13},{14},
>                {15}},{{16},{17},{18}}}}]
> ```

Not always though, will fail for example for: `{{v1, vNew}, {vNew, v6}}`. So let's just do the first flip and then `Map` with `Flatten`, so at the end you can use:

```
myArrayFlatten = Flatten /@ Flatten[#, {{1, 3}}] &
```

it automatically takes `{x,y,z}` to be column vector.

I don't understand everything well enough that I can post here quick explanation but a good start to learn more is in [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5478)

---

#### old anser, working but ugly

I really don't know why it is not that simple :/.

I hope I've not missed anything, this function will help you if dimensions are ok. So don't expect anything like [build block matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19779/5478).

```
toMatrix = Composition[

  Join @@ # &,
  Join[##, 2] & @@@ # &,
  Replace[#, x_?VectorQ :> Transpose@List@x, {2}] &

  ]
```

`Replace` part is only in case someone provides `{x,y,z}` lists and want them to be column vectors.

```
toMatrix@{
 {vNew, vNew, v1},
 {v1, v4, v1, vNew}
} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: nice function. I have no idea what it does (I lose track of things after the second @@ :) , but it seems to work so far. Something like this should really be build-in to make it easy to build matrices. I think this is one area where M is not easy to use.

Comment: @Nasser Agreed, thanks for question. Motivated me to dig more and I understood something.

Comment: @Kuba, your function is so useful. It should be renamed "makematrixfromvectors", hehe:)

Answer (score 6):

First a simpler way to get your first example:

```
(m = ArrayFlatten[Transpose /@ {{v1, v2, v3}, {v4, v5, v6}}, 1]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

An alternative way to do @bill's *undoing* trick:

```
(m2 = ArrayFlatten[Transpose /@ {{v1, ## & @@ Transpose[vNew]}, {v4, v5, v6}}, 1]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Using `ArrayReshape` as an alternative to  `ArrayFlatten`:

```
ArrayReshape[Transpose /@ {{v1, vNew}, {v4, v5, v6}}, {6, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about just breaking up the matrix and then reconstructing the same way. Here are your source vectors

```
v1 = {1, 2, 3}; vNew = {{4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}};
v4 = {10, 11, 12}; v5 = {13, 14, 15}; v6 = {16, 17, 18};
```

So now define and reconstruct:

```
{v2, v3} = Transpose[vNew]; 
ArrayFlatten[{Transpose@{v1, v2, v3}, Transpose@{v4, v5, v6}}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

If you want to do it all in one command:

```
ArrayFlatten[{Transpose@Partition[Flatten[{v1, Transpose@vNew}], 3], Transpose@{v4, v5, v6}}, 1]
```