# How to convert multidimensional matrix into regular matrix?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have this multidimensional matrix:

```
{{{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}}, {{{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}}, {{d1, d2}, {d3, d4}}}}
```

I would like to convert it into this regular matrix:

```
{{a1, a2, b1, b2}, {a3, a4, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, d1, d2}, {c3, c4, d3, d4}}
```

I have tried to use Flatten and Partition, but then I get this result:

```
{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
Flatten[
   {
      {{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}}, 
      {{{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}}, {{d1, d2}, {d3, d4}}}
   }
   , 
   {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}
]
```

Have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument) for an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) for this:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}},
              {{{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}}, {{d1, d2}, {d3, d4}}}}]

(* {{a1, a2, b1, b2}, {a3, a4, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, d1, d2}, {c3, c4, d3, d4}} *)
```

Comment: IMHO this is the correct answer. +1