# Inserting rows of one matrix into rows of another matrix sequentially

Tags: matrix

I have two matrices M1 and M2. Both have same number of columns but different number of rows. I want to make a new matrix M which should have 1st row form M1, second row form M2, third row form M1, fourth row from m2 and so on. For example,

```
M1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
M2 = {{10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}, {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}};
```

and my final matrix should be

```
M = {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 11, 12}, {4, 5, 6}, {13, 14, 15}, {7, 8, 9}, {16, 17, 18}, {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}};
```

Please note length of each matrix is over 1000. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Join @@ Flatten[{M1, M2}, {{2}, {1}}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 11, 12}, {4, 5, 6}, {13, 14, 15}, {7, 8, 9}, {16, 17,
   18}, {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}} *)
```

[Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument/126#126) for using the second argument of `Flatten` to transpose a ragged array.

---

**Update:** even shorter (big praise to `Flatten`):

```
Flatten[{M1, M2}, {2, 1}]
```

Comment: +1 nice usage of `Flatten`!

Comment: Thanks! I discovered it from a SE Q&A and I'm trying to dig it out to give proper credit.

Comment: +1 One of the fastest answers ever given :)

Comment: @seismatica Thanks for quick reply. I verified your codes in my data. It works so well. Thank you so much. You saved my life!  ::::))))

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is with `Riffle`:

```
If[Length[M1] > Length[M2],
 Riffle[M1, M2, {2, 2 Length@M2, 2}],
 Riffle[M2, M1, {1, 2 Length@M1, 2}]
]
```

but the `Flatten` method is nicer, since it doesn't need the length-comparison logic.

Edited to reflect kguler's nice use of the third `Riffle` option.

Comment: Very nice use of `Riffle`! It seems that your code will duplicate the `{16, 17, 18}`. I think using `[[Length[M1]+1 ;; -1]]` will fix that. Also, I think you can just use  `Riffle[M1, M2, {2, -1, 2}]` though your use of `Riffle` is perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: (+1) You can also use the simpler `Riffle[M2,M1,{1,2 Length@M1,2}]` as the 3rd argument of `If`.

Comment: @seismatica, you need the Length in the third argument and not -1 because otherwise it will repeat.  Try, for example, with M2 = {{10,11,12}};

Comment: @evanb Then it would default to your `True` case of `If`. I don't think you have to worry (in your older code) about riffling the longer `M2` into the shorter `M1` in the `False` case, since `M2` will not run out and repeat. I think your old code (with my `-1`) was `If[Length[M1] > Length[M2], Riffle[M1, M2, {2, 2 Length[M2], 2}], Join[Riffle[M1, M2, {2, -1, 2}], M2[[Length[M1] + 1 ;; -1]]]]`

Comment: My comment for the `-1` was only for the `False` case. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. You're right, you need `{2, 2Length@M2, 2}]` for the `True` case in the old code, otherwise M2 would repeat. However, this also means that you can use `Riffle[M2, M1, {1, -1, 2}]` for your `True` case in the _new_ code using @Pickett's trick of `Riffle` at the first position.