# Collecting specific Lists of data in coordinate form

Tags: list-manipulation

Note: This might be trivial for many of the users but i am new to mathematica so i don't know!!!

Question:
Suppose i have three list of data as follows:

```
List1 = {{a11}, {a21, a22}, {a31, a32, a33}};
List2 = {{b11}, {b21, b22}, {b31, b32, b33}};
List3 = {{c11}, {c21, c22}, {c31, c32, c33}};
```

Here all three list have the same length, i.e. 
$Length[{List}_1]=Length[{List}_2]=Length[{List}_3]$

Can someone write me a simple fast function $f$ that can do the following:

> ```
> {{a11, b11, c11}, {a21, b21, c21}, {a31, b31, c31}, {a22, b22, 
>  c22}, {a32, b32, c32}, {a33, b33, c33}}
> ```

Comment: This looks very much like Mathematica code copied as LaTeX. I strongly suggest refraining from using subscripts in the classical manner in Mathematica. All sorts of issues are bound to come up.

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

```
f = Flatten[{##}, {3, 2}] &
```

[ref: Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/5478)

Old:

```
f[lists__]:=Transpose[Flatten/@ {lists}]
```