# Transpose two uneven lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to plot two lists using the [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) command. I need to merge two lists.

The two lists I have are:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....}
b = { {1}, {0, 0}, {2, 248, 234, 5, 6}, ...}
```

I need each element of list "`a`" to map to list '`b`'s individual lists. For example, it should look like:

```
{{1,1},{2,0},{2,0},{3,2},{3,248},{3,234},{3,5},{3,6}...}
```

I have tried something like merge partition function but did not help.

**What kind of function should I use?**

Comment: @Kuba `MapThread[Prepend,{Flatten[b],a}]` ?

Comment: @Kuba I think OP wants the result to be a list of 2-element lists. PeterRoberge, I don't think that code works when the lengths of Flatten[b] and a are different, and moreover if the lengths were the same we would be trying to prepend onto an atomic expression (Number), which probably would give an error.

Comment: @PeterRoberge wasn't paying attention :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Flatten[MapThread[Outer[({#1, #2}&), #1, #2]&, {List /@ a, b}], 2]
```

`a` should be a list, `b` should be a list of lists.

Comment: `MapThread[Function[{x}, {#1, x}] /@ #2 &, {a, b}]~Flatten~1`

Comment: @march This is much nicer, though I admit I don't like the inline notation. I'm a beginner myself to the Wolfram language, so I appreciate seeing new techniques like this, thank you.

Comment: I think you'll learn to love it, eventually. We all do :) In any case, here's the more verbose version: `Flatten[MapThread[Map[Function[{x}, {#1, x}], #2] &, {a, b}], 1]`

Comment: @march. "we all do" -- I don't, so speak for yourself only.

Comment: @m_goldberg. Well, okay. One person's readability is another person's obfuscation. Check out Simon Woods' answer!

Answer (score 6):

This solution is conceptually similar to that of C. Woods, except that it uses `PadLeft[]` + `Transpose[]` to do the job:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {{1}, {0, 0}, {2, 248, 234, 5, 6}};
Flatten[MapThread[Transpose[PadLeft[{#1}, {2, Automatic}, #2]] &, {b, a}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {3, 248}, {3, 234}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Thread@*List~MapThread~{a, b}~Flatten~1
```

Answer (score 5):

With @J.M's `a` and `b`:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {{1}, {0, 0}, {2, 248, 234, 5, 6}};
```

maybe something like:

```
Thread[Flatten /@ {Table[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread[{a, Length /@ b}], b}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {3, 248}, {3, 234}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[Thread /@ Flatten[{a, b}, {{2}, {1}}], {_, _}, {-2}]
```

> `{{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {3, 248}, {3, 234}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}`

```
Thread /@ Flatten[{a, b}, {{2}, {1}}]
```

> `{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 0}, {2, 0}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 248}, {3, 234}, {3, 5}, {3,  6}}, {4}, {5}, {6}}`

**Edit**

Using the suggestion made by [garej](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/24604/garej) in a comment:

```
Select[#, ListQ] & @ Flatten[#, 1] & @ (Thread /@ Flatten[#, {{2}, {1}}] &) @ {a, b}
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {3, 248}, {3, 234}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}

I assumed the lists to be 'ragged', hence the use of [Flatten](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106)

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
b = { {1}, {0, 0}, {2, 248, 234, 5, 6}}
```

Comment: nice use of `Flatten` as transposing tool +1; `Cases` for exotica here? :)) aslo `Flatten[Thread /@ Flatten[{a, b}, {{2}, {1}}], 1]`