# Combining the entries of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists `{a, b, c, d, e}` and `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. I want to creat a new list of tuples as follows `{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}}`. Is there a command in Mathematica that allows me to do this?

Comment: Try `Transpose`.

Comment: `(Transpose@# == Thread@# == Flatten[#, {{2}}] == 
    MapThread[List, #] == Inner[List, Sequence @@ #, List]) &@{list1, list2}` => True. Note that [Flatten](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106) will work with 'ragged' arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d, e};
list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
list = Thread@{list1, list2}

{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}}
```

Comment: As Kuba states:  `x = {a,b,c,d,e}; y = {1,2,3,4,5}; Transpose[{x,y}]`.