# Adding the data of different tables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three tables of data say

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};
```

First I want to add `t1` and `t2` such that first data in the brace remains same but the second data of the two tables are added up.

For an example:

```
tsum1 = {{1,5},{2,6},{3,9}};
```

How can I do it in *Mathematica*?

If I want to add `t1`, `t2` and `t3` (`t3` has less number of data set than `t1` and `t2`) such that first data points remain same but the second ones are added up.

For an example

```
tsum2 = {{1,8},{2,9},{3,9}};
```

How can I do it with *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 6):

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};

sum[x : (_?ArrayQ ..)] := Module[
  {maxLen, xp, yp},
  maxLen = Max[Length /@ {x}];
  xp = Select[{x}, Length[#] == maxLen &][[1, All, 1]];
  yp = Plus @@ (PadRight[#[[All, 2]], maxLen, 0] & /@ {x});
  Transpose[{xp, yp}]]

tsum1 = sum[t1, t2]

(*  {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}  *)

tsum2 = sum[t1, t2, t3]

(*  {{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}  *)
```

**EDIT:** A more robust approach using [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)

```
sum2[x : (_?ArrayQ ..)] := (Join @@ {x}) //.
  {s___, {a_, b_}, m___, {a_, c_}, e___} :>
   {s, {a, b + c}, m, e}

tsum1 = sum2[t1, t2]

(*  {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}  *)

tsum2 = sum2[t1, t2, t3]

(*  {{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}  *)

t4 = {{3, 5}, {1, 3}};

tsum3 = sum2[t1, t2, t4]

(*  {{1, 8}, {2, 6}, {3, 14}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) and [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html). Or [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html) with `Total`.

```
{#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[Join @@ {t1, t2, t3}, First]
```

or

```
KeyValueMap[{#1, Total@#2[[All, 2]]} &]@GroupBy[Join @@ {t1, t2, t3}, First]
```

both give

> ```
> {{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I were to use `GroupBy`, I'd do: `KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, #1] &]@
 GroupBy[Join[t1, t2, t3], First -> Rest, Total]`.

Answer (score 3):

A short one-liner, taking advantage of the second argument of `Flatten` to perform a ragged transpose:

```
{First@#1, Tr@#2} & @@@ Flatten[{t1, t2, t3}, {{2}, {3}}]
```

(Thank to [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) for changing

```
Thread /@ Flatten[{t1, t2, t3}, {{2}}]
```

to

```
Flatten[{t1, t2, t3}, {{2}, {3}}] )
```

Comment: Equivalently `{First@#1, Tr@#2} & @@@ Flatten[{t1, t2, t3}, {{2}, {3}}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods. Thank you! I was looking for that, but I still haven't  sat down and really figured out that second argument to `Flatten` (despite the nice answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument)), and so I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

`MapThread` with 2 arrays of equal lengths

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};

MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]]} &, {t1, t2}]
```

{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}

`MapThread` with 3 arrays of unequal lengths

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};
```

`PadRight` automatically pads with `{0,0}`

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]] + #3[[2]]} &, PadRight[{t1, t2, t3}]]
```

{{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}

More flexible are `Association`-related functions

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ Merge[Total] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Join[t1, t2, t3]
```

{{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}

Edmund's solution can be simplified to

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[Join[t1, t2, t3], First -> Last, Total]
```

{{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `With`, `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};

With[{lst = {t1, t2}, l = Length@{t1, t2}}, 
Reap[Do[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ Join @@ #, {i, l}], _, {#1, Total@#2/l} &][[2]] &@lst]

(*{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}*)

With[{lst = {t1, t2, t3}, l = Length@{t1, t2, t3}}, 
Reap[Do[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ Join @@ #, {i, l}], _, {#1, Total@#2/l} &][[2]] &@lst]

(*{{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}*)
```

---

```
MapIndexed[{First@#2, Total@#1} &, 
 Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[Last@#, First@#] &, Flatten[{t1, t2, t3}, 1]]]

(* {{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `ArrayReduce`:**

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};

s1 = ArrayReduce[
  Total@*Union, #[[All, All, 1]] &@PadRight[{t1, t2, t3}], 1];

s2 = ArrayReduce[Total, #[[All, All, 2]] &@PadRight[{t1, t2, t3}], 1];

Transpose[{s1, s2}]
```

> {{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}

Answer (score 3):

## Recommend

Convert `List` to `Association`, then Merge the Associations, finally convert `Association` to `List`.

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
t1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}};

(*Create associations*)
myListToAssociation[lst_] := 
  assoc1 = Association[(#1 -> #2) & @@@ lst];

(*Merge associations and total the values*)
assocSum = Merge[myListToAssociation /@ {t1, t2, t3}, Total]

(*Convert the association back to a list*)
tsum2 = {#, assocSum[#]} & /@ Keys[assocSum]
```

```
<|1 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 9|>
{{1, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}
```

## DO NOT recommend

zip (to some degree) the lists, then processing the data.

```
t1 = {{a2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{a1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};

tsum1 = MapThread[{First[#1], Last[#1] + Last[#2]} &, {t2, t1}]
```

```
{{a1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on using `Flatten` to transpose a ragged array:

```
MapThread[{First@#1,Total[#2]}&,(Flatten[{t1,t2,t3},{{3},{2}}])]

(* {{1,8},{2,9},{3,9}} *)
```