# List extraction

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following list:

```
l1={{{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {3, 1}, {4, 9}, {5, 8}, {6, 8}, {7, 5},
{8, 8},{9, 5}, {10, 9}, {11, 1}, {12, 1}}, {{1, 8}, {2, 6}, {3, 6}, {4, 
7}, {5, 7}, {6, 10}, {7, 9}, {8, 6}, {9, 9}, {10, 8}, {11, 
10}, {12, 7}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 10}, {5, 1}, {6, 
1}, {7, 1}, {8, 1}, {9, 1}, {10, 2}, {11, 2}, {12, 4}}, {{1, 
6}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 9}, {6, 5}, {7, 4}, {8, 9}, {9, 
7}, {10, 10}, {11, 5}, {12, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 1}, {3, 10}, {4, 
5}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {9, 4}, {10, 5}, {11, 7}, {12, 
8}}, {{1, 9}, {2, 10}, {3, 7}, {4, 2}, {5, 10}, {6, 3}, {7, 8}, {8,
10}, {9, 8}, {10, 1}, {11, 4}, {12, 10}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 
5}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, {6, 6}, {7, 2}, {8, 5}, {9, 10}, {10, 7}, {11, 
6}, {12, 2}}, {{1, 10}, {2, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 1}, {5, 4}, {6, 7}, {7,
10}, {8, 2}, {9, 3}, {10, 6}, {11, 9}, {12, 5}}, {{1, 7}, {2, 
3}, {3, 9}, {4, 6}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 7}, {8, 4}, {9, 6}, {10, 
3}, {11, 8}, {12, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 9}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}, {6,
9}, {7, 3}, {8, 7}, {9, 2}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}, {12, 9}}};
```

How can I create this list:

```
l2={{4, 8, 1, 6, 5, 9, 3, 10, 7, 2}, {8, 6, 2, 4, 1, 10, 5, 7, 3, 9}, {1,
6, 3, 2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 9, 4}, {9, 7, 10, 3, 5, 2, 8, 1, 6, 4}, {8, 7,
1, 9, 2, 10, 6, 4, 5, 3}, {8, 10, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 9}, {5, 9, 
1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 10, 7, 3}, {8, 6, 1, 9, 3, 10, 5, 2, 4, 7}, {5, 8, 1,
7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6, 2}, {9, 8, 2, 10, 5, 1, 7, 6, 3, 4}, {1, 10, 2, 
5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 8, 3}, {1, 7, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 5, 3, 9}}
```

Using `l1[[All, #, 2]] & /@ Range[1, Length[l1[[All;2]]]]` seems particularily inelegant... I'm sure there's a better way.

Each sublist being the second element of each column of the `l1` matrix.

Comment: `Transpose[l1, {3, 2, 1}][[2]]`

Comment: `Transpose@Map[Last, l1, {2}]`

Comment: I would like to understand, why {3,2,1} in Marius' answer?

Comment: `Transpose@l1[[;; , ;; , 2]]`

Comment: The section labelled _Iteration Order_ in the answer [(14810)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/142) discusses index gymnastics of the kind specified by `{3,2,1}`.  That answer concerns `Flatten`, but it might still be useful if one can make a mental substitution according to the identity `Transpose[m, {i, j, k}] === Flatten[m, {{i}, {j}, {k}}]`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in a number of ways:

- by replacing the pairs with their second elements:

`l1 /. {a_, b_} -> b // Transpose`

- or by mapping `Last` onto `l1` on level `2`:

`Transpose @ Map[Last, l1, {2}]`

- or by explicitly taking the second elements:

`Transpose @ l1[[;; , ;; , 2]] (* credit: N.J.Evans *)`

- or with a clever use of `Transpose`:

`Transpose[l1, {3, 2, 1}][[2]] (* credit: Marius Ladegård Meyer *)`

---

Or (unnecessarily overcomplicated, though):

```
Transpose @ ArrayReshape[Cases[l1, {a_, b_} :> b, 2], Drop[Dimensions[l1], -1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
♯1 = #2 & @@@ # & /@ # &;
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
♯1@l1
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]