# Trouble in understanding `Table`

Tags: matrix, programming, list-manipulation

Even after, not only seeing, but understanding on *Mathematica SE* and also using `Table`. I am afraid, if I still understand it.

Here is one example, which I couldn't understand. I am using `Table` to display a matrix subject to the condition as mentioned below:

```
In[257]:= 
res1 = Table[KroneckerDelta[j - (1 + i)], {j, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 10}];

MatrixForm[res1]
```

This is the output:

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
Which I couldn't understand is, `KroneckerDelta[j-(1 + i)]` is a constrain. Now as per `Table` [definition(where @WReach has used to display matrix with indices, to show the working of `Table`)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument/14810#14810). First, `j` should run for every fix value of `i` i.e. `j` should run from `0` to `10` for each value of `i` and keep on untill `i=i_max`, analogous to `Do` loop first of `j` then of `i`. By making use of, all of this, assuming `i = 0` to begin with, so `KroneckerDelta[j-(1 + 0)] = KroneckerDelta[j-1]`. Which means a value( i.e. `1`) at position `(0,1)`, instead I am getting at `(1,0)`. Are things just the other way round?

Mathematica 11.0.1
Ubuntu16.04

Comment: Does this help? `res1 = Table[ToString[{i, j}], {j, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 10}];
MatrixForm[res1]`

Comment: I don't see how the working of `Table` can be made more clear than e.g. `Table[Row[{"(i=", i, "; j=", j, ")"}], {j, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 10}] // MatrixForm`.

Comment: @NicholasG Thanks for this. I got it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks to you also. Now I see the things are other way round first all the rows increment then the columns, unlike the `Do` loop

Comment: iterator handling in `Table` and `Do` is exactly the same. Of course there is no sense of rows and columns in a `Do` loop.

Comment: @george2079 I got it, they are same. I was seeing the transpose version.