# Applying the vec operator

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

How to apply the [$\operatorname{vec}$ operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) in *Mathematica*? For example, how can I transform a $2 \times 2$ matrix into a $1 \times 4$ matrix as follows?
$$
    \operatorname{vec}\left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
      a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
      a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} 
    \end{bmatrix}
    \right)
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      a_{1,1}  \\
      a_{2,1}  \\
      a_{1,2}  \\
     a_{2,2} 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: vector and matrix are vague terms in Mathematica so please add input and expected output in terms of Mathematica code in order to make the question clear.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  Please see the additional example of `Flatten` that I added afterward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to do this in a single operation.

```
in = Array[a, {2, 2}]

Flatten[in, {2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}}
>
> {a[1, 1], a[2, 1], a[1, 2], a[2, 2]}
> ```

In *Mathematica* there are only vectors (lists), not column vectors and row vectors.  However if you wish to convert a vector into an array with rows of length one for output the computationally fastest method is typically [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

```
Partition[{a[1, 1], a[2, 1], a[1, 2], a[2, 2]}, 1]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1]}, {a[2, 1]}, {a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 2]}}
> ```

If that is your goal from the start you can also do that in a single operation using `Flatten`:

```
Flatten[{in}, {3, 2}]     (* note the extra {} around in *)
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1]}, {a[2, 1]}, {a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 2]}}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/121)

Comment: Unless OP sees column vector as: `List /@ {a[1, 1], a[2, 1], a[1, 2], a[2, 2]}`

Comment: @Kuba Good point.  There is no such thing as a column vector in *Mathematica* as you know, but that doesn't mean the OP doesn't potentially want a series of one element rows...

Answer (score 4):

```
{{1, 2}, {4, 5}} // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 2 \\
> 4 & 5 
> \end{bmatrix}

```
ArrayReshape[Transpose[%], {4, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 4\\
> 2\\
> 5
> \end{bmatrix}

Thanks to @cyrille.piatecki for the use of `Transpose[]`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this simple module

```
vec[mat_] := 
 Module[{a = mat}, 
  ArrayReshape[Transpose[
   a], {Dimensions[mat][[1]] Dimensions[mat][[2]], 1}]]
```

apply with

```
aa = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
```

this gives the expected result

```
vec[aa] // MatrixForm
```