# Flattening a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with dimensions `{1000, 1000, 1}` and I would like it to have dimensions `{1000, 1000}`. But `Flatten[list,1]` makes it `{1000000, 1}` and I've also tried `Flatten[list,-1]` with no success. Can I use flatten to do this or will I need a different command?

Comment: Maybe `Flatten /@ list`?

Comment: @anderstood Perfect, that works, thanks!

Comment: Also `list[[All, All, 1]]` will work.

Comment: `Flatten[list, {1, 3}]` also works, but `ArrayReshape[list, Most@Dimensions@list]` might be fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of similar shape to the one in the question:

```
$a = Array[a[##] &, {3, 3, 1}];
$a // MatrixForm
```

[image: unflattened array]

... we can tell `Flatten` to leave level one untouched but flatten levels two and three together:

```
Flatten[$a, {{1}, {2, 3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: partially flattened array]

This syntax is the subject of the question [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142).