# Flatten a list at some level

Tags: list-manipulation

I wonder if is possible flatten a list at the last level without flattening at the first level, I think that isn't a good explanation so here is my code

```
Table[Table[{Position[points[dx, dy, n], {i, j}][[1]], 
   Position[points[dx, dy, n], Vec[dx, dy, n, i, j][[k]]][[1]]}, {k, 
   1, Dimensions[Vec[dx, dy, n, i, j]][[1]]}], {j, -n, n}, {i, -n, n}]
```

This input gives me

```
{{{{{1}, {4}}, {{1}, {2}}}, {{{4}, {1}}, {{4}, {7}}, {{4}, {5}}},
{{{7}, {4}}, {{7}, {8}}}}, {{{{2}, {5}}, {{2}, {1}}, {{2}, {3}}},
{{{5}, {2}}, {{5}, {8}}, {{5}, {4}}, {{5}, {6}}}, {{{8}, {5}}, {{8},
{7}}, {{8}, {9}}}}, {{{{3}, {6}}, {{3}, {2}}}, {{{6}, {3}}, {{6},
{9}}, {{6}, {5}}}, {{{9}, {6}}, {{9}, {8}}}}}
```

If I do this I get the desired result

```
Flatten[Table[
  Table[Flatten[{Position[points[dx, dy, n], {i, j}][[1]], 
     Position[points[dx, dy, n], Vec[dx, dy, n, i, j][[k]]][[1]]}, 
    1], {k, 1, Dimensions[Vec[dx, dy, n, i, j]][[1]]}], {j, -n, 
   n}, {i, -n, n}], 2]
```

Which is

```
{{1, 4}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 7}, {4, 5}, {7, 4}, {7, 8}, {2, 5}, {2, 
  1}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 8}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 
  9}, {3, 6}, {3, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 9}, {6, 5}, {9, 6}, {9, 8}}
```

My question is if there is a way to do this without using `Flatten` twice.
I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Why not avoid the innermost lists altogether? Assuming you know that there will always be one match, you can use `Position[…][[1,1]]`. Then you only need one a simple `Flatten` for the outer lists.

Comment: Actually, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to `Flatten` there is `Level[data, {3}][[All, All, 1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) with a list second argument:

```
data = {
    {
        {{{1},{4}},{{1},{2}}},
        {{{4},{1}},{{4},{7}},{{4},{5}}},
        {{{7},{4}},{{7},{8}}}
    },
    {
        {{{2},{5}},{{2},{1}},{{2},{3}}},
        {{{5},{2}},{{5},{8}},{{5},{4}},{{5},{6}}},
        {{{8},{5}},{{8},{7}},{{8},{9}}}
    },
    {
        {{{3},{6}},{{3},{2}}},
        {{{6},{3}},{{6},{9}},{{6},{5}}},
        {{{9},{6}},{{9},{8}}}
    }
};

Flatten[data, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
```

> {{1, 4}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 7}, {4, 5}, {7, 4}, {7, 8}, {2, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 
>     3}, {5, 2}, {5, 8}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {3, 6}, {3, 
>     2}, {6, 3}, {6, 9}, {6, 5}, {9, 6}, {9, 8}}

Comment: This worked too. But, actually I'm not familiar with`Flatten` at all, so could you explain me why it works?

Comment: @AlbertoNavarro: you can begin by reading the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html). They try some of the examples there. If you have more specific questions, word them in such a way that they show the effort you put into them.

Comment: The second argument to `Flatten` is discussed at length in [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142).