# Manipulation of 3D matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

Assume that we have a 3D array `x`, and we would like to split it into 2D slices then cut every slice into some small patches and get all patches in single list `t`. How to do this?

What I have done is to extract a 2D slice and then cut it into patches but how to do this with all slices in one shot. For example:

```
x = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {8, 8, 8}]; (* x is an 8x8x8 array *)
y = x[[1, ;;, ;;]];                    (* y is an 8x8 array   *)
z = Partition[y, {2, 2}, {2, 2}];      (* z is a 4x4x2x2 array *)
t = Flatten[z, 1];                     (* t is a 16x2x2 array *)
```

How to repeat this for all `x` $ (8\times8\times8) $ and get some vector `t` $ (128\times2\times2) $?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just a quick pointer:  `x[[1,;;,;;]]` is a bit easier to read as `x[[1,All,All]]` but actually it is equivalent to `x[[1]]`.

Comment: yep, u r right :)

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayReshape` is constructive here too (together with [the somewhat confusing fourth syntax of `Flatten`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument)):

```
ArrayReshape[x, {32, 2, 4, 2}];
Flatten[%, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}}]
```

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for help

Comment: @AlienTsukuba Glad if it indeed helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a helper function

```
helper[list_] := Partition[list, {2, 2}, {2, 2}]
```

The you can get what you want by using `Map` on `x`:

```
result = Flatten[helper /@ x, 2];
Dimensions@result
(* {128, 2, 2} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Jason B, it works fine :)