# Flatten a four dimensional array into a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the simplest way to transform an array of the form

```
{{{{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}, 
{{a13, a14}, {a23, a24}}}, 
{{{a31, a32}, {a41, a42}}, 
{{a33, a34}, {a43, a44}}}}
```

To the matrix

```
{{a11,a12,a13,a14},
{a21,a22,a23,a24},
{a31,a32,a33,a34},
{a41,a42,a43,a44}}
```

I understand I should use `Flatten`, but I cannot figure out how to denote the levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) is the ticket:

```
a = {{{{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}, {{a13, a14}, {a23, a24}}}, {{{a31, a32}, {a41, a42}}, {{a33, a34}, {a43, a44}}}};
b = {{a11, a12, a13, a14}, {a21, a22, a23, a24}, {a31, a32, a33, a34}, {a41, a42, a43, a44}};

ArrayFlatten[a] == b
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

As Roman says, [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten) is the simplest, but you could use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) as well:

```
Flatten[
    {
    {{{a11,a12},{a21,a22}},{{a13,a14},{a23,a24}}},
    {{{a31,a32},{a41,a42}},{{a33,a34},{a43,a44}}}
    },
    {{1,3}, {2,4}}
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{a11} & \text{a12} & \text{a13} & \text{a14} \\
>  \text{a21} & \text{a22} & \text{a23} & \text{a24} \\
>  \text{a31} & \text{a32} & \text{a33} & \text{a34} \\
>  \text{a41} & \text{a42} & \text{a43} & \text{a44} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Is there any simple explanation why `{{1,3},{2,4}}` works?

Comment: @tst: If you don't feel like dealing with the `Flatten[]` levels, you can also [Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) it "all the way" and then [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) it back into 4-element lists, e.g., `
{{{{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}, {{a13, a14}, {a23, a24}}}, {{{a31, 
      a32}, {a41, a42}}, {{a33, a34}, {a43, a44}}}} // Flatten // Partition[#, 4]& `

Comment: @tst Explanations about `{{1,3},{2,4}}` can be found in [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142).  Not sure about "simple", however :)