# How to assemble matrices?

Tags: matrix

I'm a beginner in Mathematica and have a very basic question.

Suppose I have made the following matrices (4x4).
$$A,B,C,D,$$
and I want to make the larger matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I wish to add to my question.  I tried ArrayFlatten for the following:
$A$ is a 4x2 matrix, $B$ is a 4x4 matrix, and $C$ is a 4x6 matrix.  I tried this to construct a 4x12 matrix:
X = ArrayFlatten[{A,B,C}]
However, Dimensions[X] returns 3x4 in my notebook instead of 4x12.  What I'm really trying to do is to join the matrices together.  Please help.  Thanks.

How to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[{{A, B}, {C, D}}]`

Answer (score 3):

Some example matrices matching your dimensions:

```
m1 = Array[Subscript[a,##]&, {4,2}];
m2 = Array[Subscript[b,##]&, {4,4}];
m3 = Array[Subscript[c,##]&, {4,6}];
```

For example:

```
m1 //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The problem with your use of [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten) was that it was missing brackets. The following works fine:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{m1, m2, m3}}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} & c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} & c_{1,4} & c_{1,5} & c_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} & c_{2,1} & c_{2,2} & c_{2,3} & c_{2,4} & c_{2,5} & c_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3} & b_{3,4} & c_{3,1} & c_{3,2} & c_{3,3} & c_{3,4} & c_{3,5} & c_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & b_{4,1} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} & c_{4,1} & c_{4,2} & c_{4,3} & c_{4,4} & c_{4,5} & c_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Another alternative is to use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join):

```
Join[m1, m2, m3, 2] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} & c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} & c_{1,4} & c_{1,5} & c_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} & c_{2,1} & c_{2,2} & c_{2,3} & c_{2,4} & c_{2,5} & c_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3} & b_{3,4} & c_{3,1} & c_{3,2} & c_{3,3} & c_{3,4} & c_{3,5} & c_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & b_{4,1} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} & c_{4,1} & c_{4,2} & c_{4,3} & c_{4,4} & c_{4,5} & c_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Finally, if you try to construct a matrix of matrices, another possibility is to use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten):

```
Flatten[{{m1, m2, m3}}, {{1,3}, {2,4}}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} & c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} & c_{1,4} & c_{1,5} & c_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} & c_{2,1} & c_{2,2} & c_{2,3} & c_{2,4} & c_{2,5} & c_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3} & b_{3,4} & c_{3,1} & c_{3,2} & c_{3,3} & c_{3,4} & c_{3,5} & c_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & b_{4,1} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} & c_{4,1} & c_{4,2} & c_{4,3} & c_{4,4} & c_{4,5} & c_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The nice thing about using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) is that the column dimensions don't have to match. For example:

```
Flatten[{{m1, m2}, {m3}}, {{1,3}, {2,4}}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3} & b_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & b_{4,1} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} \\
>  c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} & c_{1,4} & c_{1,5} & c_{1,6} \\
>  c_{2,1} & c_{2,2} & c_{2,3} & c_{2,4} & c_{2,5} & c_{2,6} \\
>  c_{3,1} & c_{3,2} & c_{3,3} & c_{3,4} & c_{3,5} & c_{3,6} \\
>  c_{4,1} & c_{4,2} & c_{4,3} & c_{4,4} & c_{4,5} & c_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: what is the meaning of the second argument {{1,3},{2,4}}?

Comment: @D.B. See the answers to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/45431.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ArrayFlatten`.  For example:

```
    With[{AA = Array[a, {4, 4}], BB = Array[b, {4, 4}], 
   CC = Array[c, {4, 4}], DD = Array[d, {4, 4}]}, 
  ArrayFlatten[{{AA, BB}, {CC, DD}}]] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) & a(1,4) & b(1,1) & b(1,2) &
>    b(1,3) & b(1,4) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) & a(2,4) & b(2,1) & b(2,2) &
>    b(2,3) & b(2,4) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) & a(3,4) & b(3,1) & b(3,2) &
>    b(3,3) & b(3,4) \\
>  a(4,1) & a(4,2) & a(4,3) & a(4,4) & b(4,1) & b(4,2) &
>    b(4,3) & b(4,4) \\
>  c(1,1) & c(1,2) & c(1,3) & c(1,4) & d(1,1) & d(1,2) &
>    d(1,3) & d(1,4) \\
>  c(2,1) & c(2,2) & c(2,3) & c(2,4) & d(2,1) & d(2,2) &
>    d(2,3) & d(2,4) \\
>  c(3,1) & c(3,2) & c(3,3) & c(3,4) & d(3,1) & d(3,2) &
>    d(3,3) & d(3,4) \\
>  c(4,1) & c(4,2) & c(4,3) & c(4,4) & d(4,1) & d(4,2) &
>    d(4,3) & d(4,4) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Here is the result of your code $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
 c(1,1) & c(1,2) & d(1,1) & d(1,2) & d(1,3) \\
 c(2,1) & c(2,2) & d(2,1) & d(2,2) & d(2,3) \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ Is this it?

Comment: My original answer used unequally sized rectangular matrices.  I think such examples easily are made more specific without, but show (for example) how the sizes of the matrices must agree.