# Decomposing a list into several two coordinate lists

Tags: list-manipulation

How can the following list can be decomposed into separate two coordinate lists?

```
list = {{1, {0}}, {2, {0}}, {3, {-2, 0, 2}}, {4, {-2, 0, 2}}, {5, {-2, 0, 2}}};
```

what I wish to obtain is

```
list1 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
list2 = {{3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}};
list3 = {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}};
```

or

```
list1 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
list2 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -2},{5, -2}};
list3 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}};
```

or

```
list1 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}};
list2 = {{3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
list3 = {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}};
```

Comment: can you specify the rule for the list composition?

Comment: @Fraccalo, consider this as an example for an output of a pitchfork bifurcation solution, it's not that relevant though.

Comment: well, the point is that the three lists seem quite different, one can write ad hoc codes for obtaining one of them, but such codes wouldn't be general

Comment: @Fraccalo, the idea is that each list is decomposed from the first,second, or third element of the second sublist. I gave several examples for an output that can separate them to have three lines that can be plotted in a graph.

Comment: @jarhead Your second set of lists does not make sense to me when compared with the other two. Can you confirm that Set-2 is a desired outcome and not  (say) `{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}, {{3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}, {{3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}}` (and there are other possibilities)?  @march has given a very nice solution based on  a ragged Transpose which is adaptable to Set-1 but (it seems to me) not Set-2

Answer (score 3):

Implement a ragged transpose after turning each sublist into a list of pairs, like so:

```
list = {{1, {0}}, {2, {0}}, {3, {-2, 0, 2}}, {4, {-2, 0, 2}}, {5, {-2,0, 2}}};
Flatten[Thread /@ list, {2}]
(* {{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}},
    {{3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}},
    {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}} *)
```

If you really want to name these sublists, you can do

```
Clear[list1, list2, list3]
{list1, list2, list3} = Flatten[Thread /@ list, {2}];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List@@Flatten/@ (list /. {a_, {b_, 0, d_}} -> { a, 0} )
List@@Flatten/@ (list /. {a_, {b_, 0, d_}} -> { a, b} )
List@@Flatten/@ (list /. {a_, {b_, 0, d_}} -> { a, d} )
```

Answer (score 2):

The first list:

```
listsa = GatherBy[Join @@ (Thread /@ list), Last];
Column[listsa]
```

[image]

The second list:

```
listsb1 = Join @@@ 
   GatherBy[Thread[Thread /@ list, List, {3, 5}] /. {{a_, b_}} :> {a, b}, #[[-1, -1]] &];
```

or

```
listsb2 = TemporalData[Transpose@PadLeft[#[[All, -1]]], {#[[All, 1]]}]["Paths"] &@list;

listsb1 == listsb2
```

> True

```
Column[listsb1]
```

[image]

The third:

```
listsc = Join[##, 2] & @@ Map[List, Thread /@ list, {-2}];
Column[listsc]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's still not fully clear what are you exactly looking for, but this is a piece of code that might help you (it gives you the first set of lists you give in your question). It can easily be readapted for the other cases:

```
list = {{1, {0}}, {2, {0}}, {3, {-2, 0, 2}}, {4, {-2, 0, 2}}, {5, {-2,0, 2}}};

ind = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[list[[;; , 2]]]
```

> {0, -2, 2}

```
{list1, list2, list3} =  Cases[list, {a_, b_} /; MemberQ[b, #] -> {a, #}] & /@ ind
```

> {{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 
>      0}}, {{3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}, {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}}

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214770/106) given by [@march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march), where the second argument of `Flatten` is used to transpose a ragged array (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106)):

**Set-1** may be generated as follows:

```
{list1a, list2a, list3a}=Distribute[#, List]&/@(list /.{x_,y_,z_}:> {y,x,z})//Flatten[#,{{2}}]&

list1a
list2a
list3a
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}
>
> {{3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}
>
> {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}

**Set 3** (as per [@march answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106))

```
{list3a, list3b, list3c}=Distribute[#, List]&/@list//Flatten[#,{{2}}]&
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}
>
> {{3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}
>
> {{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}

**Set-2**

As given by the OP the lists may be obtained as follows (in this case a simple Transpose is all that is required):

```
{list1b, list2b,list3b}=Distribute[#, List]&/@(list /.{x_,y_,z_}:> {y,x,z}/.{0}:> {0,0,0})//Transpose
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}
>
> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}
>
> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}

But perhaps the OP requires something like the following?

```
{list1x, list2x,list3x}=Distribute[#, List]&/@(list /.{x_,y_,z_}:> {z,x,y})//Flatten[#,{{2}}]&
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}
>
> {{3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}}
>
> {{3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}

**Comment**

In all cases, (as shown in the [@march answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106)), `Thread` may be substituted for `Distribute`

```
(Distribute[#, List]&/@(list /.{x_,y_,z_}:> {y,x,z})//Flatten[#,{2}]&)===(Thread/@(list /.{x_,y_,z_}:> {y,x,z})//Flatten[#,{2}]&)
```