# How do I flatten sublists while maintaining a separation between preexisting sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that looks like:

```
z={{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e}},{{b,c},{d,e},{w,e}}}
```

How would I create a list that looks like:

```
zz={{a,b,b,c,c,d,d,e},{b,c,d,e,w,e}}
```

I have tried `Flatten` but that doesn't seem to work at the desired level.

Comment: Try mapping Flatten

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can tell `Flatten` to leave level 1 as-is but to flatten levels 2 and 3 together:

```
Flatten[z, {{1}, {2, 3}}]
(* {{a, b, b, c, c, d, d, e}, {b, c, d, e, w, e}} *)
```

This syntax is quite flexible, see [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142).

Answer (score 8):

Try the map function

```
list = {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d, e}}, {{b, c}, {d, e}, {w, e}}}
Flatten /@ list
```

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you.